# Are snprintf and friends safe to use?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, printf

There was a question recently on SO ([Why on earth would anyone use strncpy instead of strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-on-earth-would-anyone-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)), which hade answers ([answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-on-earth-would-anyone-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy/1258577#1258577), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-on-earth-would-anyone-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy/1258576#1258576)), that made me uncertain about other string functions with 'n' in their name, like `snprintf` (which I have been using extensively). Is snprintf safe to use? And generally, what are the safe functions from the 'n' family?

Comment: Related: beware the different behaviors of snprintf/swprintf/snwprintf/etc and %ls and %s on different platforms. They are all different.

Comment: Only on broken, non-conformant implementations. The C standard is very clear on what these format specifiers are supposed to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`strncpy()` is an oddball function that is really misnamed - it's original purpose to to ensure that a buffer was completely initialized with the contents of a string (without overflowing the target) and the reminder of the buffer with zeros.  As I understand it, the original purpose was to handle file system directory entries - the target buffer was not really a string in the same sense as the other `strxxx()` functions in the C library. The main problem with `strncpy()` is that if the source string is larger than the destination buffer, the result will not be null terminated.

Most of the other 'n' functions that deal with strings do properly terminate the string, but there are exceptions like Microsoft's bastardized `_snprintf()`.  A proper C99 `snprintf()` will always null terminate the destination string (as long as the destination buffer has  a size greater than 0).

There's a 'Technical Report', TR 24731 that proposes a set of boundary-checking alternatives for functions that deal with strings and memory buffers. One of the goals of the TR is to have the parameters, results and error behavior of the functions be more similar across the functions.  The TR seems to have somewhat mixed acceptance, and I don't think it's widely implemented other than for Microsoft's compiler (I think MS was the main driver behind the TR).  you can get more information here:

- [TR 24731 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1173.pdf)
- [TR 24731-1 (Bounds-checking interfaces)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1225.pdf)
- [TR 24731-2 (Dynamic allocation functions)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1337.pdf)

Even if you're not a fan of the proposals, I think they make for educational reading about the issues with existing functions.

Comment: As an aside, the MS implementation is non-conforming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions

Answer (score 1):

While `snprintf` will not overrun a buffer if you give it the correct arguments, please keep in mind that it shares all of the format string vulnerabilities with other members of the `*printf` family. For example, the `%n` specifier is nasty because it can be used by attackers to write arbitrary bytes to arbitrary memory locations.  See [FIO30-C. Exclude user input from format strings](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO30-C.+Exclude+user+input+from+format+strings) from the CERT C Coding Standards wiki.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe as you long as you provide the correct length for the buffer.

Comment: Which length you provide (and whether or not you manually null terminate the end of the buffer yourself) depends on which platform you're on.

Answer (score -2):

snprintf does guarantee that the buffer won't be overwritten, but it does not guarantee null-termination.  You can use `sprintf_s` on MSVC if you're willing to be non-standard.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Actually not, snprintf doesn't guarantees buffer overflows at all. It depends on the buffer size you provided, which can be incorrect

Comment: It goes without saying that there is no CRT function that magically knows how big the buffer passed in actually is.

Comment: Well, then it goes without saying that no CRT function is "safe", and there's not much point people going around pretending that appending _s to the names of them all breaks this rule ;-)

Comment: -1: You should clarify that you're talking about the broken Microsoft implementation and not the C standard.

Comment: The C standard `snprintf` *does* guarantee that a `\0` will be written to the end of the buffer and that buffer overflow will not take place. This, of course, depends on the size argument you pass but you can do exactly the same thing to `snprintf_s` and have it fail for the same reason.

Answer (score -4):

Beware: different platforms have different behaviors concerning null termination of a string passed to `snprintf`.

Comment: `snprintf` as specified in ISO C99 is guaranteed to null-terminate.

Comment: That's what ISO C99 says: however, the behavior on certain platforms is different. You'll have to experiment and validate each platform to be sure.

Comment: Can you give an example of a platform that doesn't conform with standard C in this respoect?

Comment: Microsoft's variant, _snprintf(), doesn't terminate the destination if the buffer isn't large enough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx

Comment: Why would anyone worry about non-conformance in a nonstandard function with an underscore at the beginning of its name, when you could just wrap it with a function by the standard name and fix the lack-of-termination bug at the same time?

Comment: I would vote this down if I could.  It is absolutely false.  If you choose to use the nonstandard, differently-named _snprintf, then its behavior may be different.  However, this is not what the submitter asked.  It looks like snprintf is not available on Windows; however, you can write your own without too much difficulty.