# strncpy chosen by linker from libc instead of rom version

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, libc

I use 106Micro core and Xtensa toolchain (gcc) for ESP8266 chip.

Not sure what strncpy function is used

According to map file

```
 .text          0x4010077c       0xfa c:/sysgcc/esp8266/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/5.2.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-strncpy.o)
                0x401007b4                strncpy
```

But also in ROM, there is a function that is already present with the same name

```
        0x4000c0a0                PROVIDE (strncpy, 0x4000c0a0)
```

Since if function from libc is present in binary, seems that the ROM one was ignored. Most likely I haven't a prototype defined for ROM one (since ESP8266 has many ROM functions not explained, without an ykind of prototype) and due to  the libc was chosen.

Now how can I include the ROM version, but keep the  in program?

Thanks for clarifications,

Comment: Can you step through in your debugger and find out?

Comment: I would, but Chinese manufacturers barely knows to write a datasheet. Debugger is non existing.

Comment: If they both work the same then I guess the issue is academic. If they work differently then you can always discover which one you're using,

Comment: I don't know, the ROM version doesn't have proto and is unknown. I have to dump the content, dissassm then reconstruct, to see clearly. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @tadman It is not academic even if they are identical. Ignoring the ROM version bloats the size of executable.

Comment: How your linker script look like?

Comment: @user58697 If it's in a shared library that's already there then there's no difference. That's how `libc` is often shipped.

Comment: [Never use strncpy for any purpose.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what linker you are using, but for GNU ld the [`PROVIDE` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE.html) (with slightly different syntax) is used to:

> [...] define a symbol only if it is referenced and is not defined by any object included in the link.

Because you have provided libc, and thus a definition for `strncpy` then that will override the `PROVIDE`'ed `strncpy`.

If you remove libc from the link, the symbol will be resolved by the `PROVIDE` directive.  If you are not explicitly linking libc, you may need to use the link option [`--nodefaultlibs` or `--nostdlib`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Link-Options.html) to prevent linking code already provided.

Comment: I use GNU ld, built for Xtensa (pretty much standard gcc) The --nostdlib was given but  --nodefaultlibs was not (forgotten by me) but >>> Thank you! <<< I missed the part with override, didn't knew. Cheers!