# How do I store a converted char to binary number

Tags: c

I think you guy already heard of a code like this

```
   (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
```

I already stored this on an array but it gives me a wrong binary. 
Here's the additional code

```
int i;
char test[8];
for(i=7 ; i>=0; i--){

    test[i] =(c &(1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
}
int j = atoi(test);
printf("%d\n", j);
```

my sample was: 'I'
it gave me : 100100109

Comment: Store it in an array of characters instead of printing it? I.e. `some_array[some_index] = (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: now a real question - why do you need to store it?

Comment: i need to store it because i'm making a bit rotation cipher. I'll store it and rotate it afterwards.

Comment: As I suspected. You really don't need to. It can be achieved by few simple bit operations on the original data. But.. it's up to you, of course.

Comment: Please, Enlighten me.

Comment: [don't use `atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @Macaraune Salad You have to append the array with a zero byte because the function atoi expects a string.

Comment: You need to terminate the string `test` with a `\0` before calling `atoi`.

Comment: `atoi` converts a string with a decimal number, not a binary number. Why don't you just print the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `atoi(test);` is *undefined*. The parameter `test` (once decayed to a pointer type) must point to a NUL-terminated array of `char`. Yours isn't.

The solution is trivial here, write

```
char test[9] = {0};
```

instead to force the inclusion of a NUL-terminator . But do note that the resulting number is of the order of 10 million; perhaps therefore too big for an `int`. Use a `long` instead to be sure, along with `atol` instead of `atoi`. If you want the string to be parsed as binary, then use `strtol` passing a radix of 2.

Comment: `atoi` has no error control - should we recommend to use it? +1 anyway.

Comment: @coderredoc: `atoi` certainly has its purpose. Although that said, the C standard library I/O functions are so poor you pretty much end up writing your own.

Comment: For validated input - it's alright I suppose. Otherwise there is `strtol` which is way more sophisticated than `ato*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number formatted as string in base 2 ("binary") to an actual integer, use [`strtoul()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul):

```
const unsigned long x = strtoul("11100011", NULL, 2);
printf("x=%lu\n", x);
```

The final `2` there specifies the base, and `2` of course gives binary, and this prints `227`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in other answers, the core problem is that you don't null terminate the string. But there's various other bad practice in this program:

- [The atoi() family of functions should never be used for any purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518), since they have no error handling.
- Never use bitwise operators on signed numbers or signed integer constants. `1` is a signed type, for example. Code like `1<<15` will invoke undefined behavior on 8 and 16 bit CPUs.

A corrected program might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  unsigned int c = 100;

  char test[8+1];

  for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    test[i] = c & (1u<<(8-1-i)) ? '1' : '0';
  }
  test[8] = '\0';

  int j = (int)strtol(test, NULL, 10);
  printf("%.8d\n", j);

  return 0;
}
```

Or if you live and breathe C language operator precedence (major nerd warning), you could be cocky and just write `test[i] = c & 1u << 8-1-i ? '1' : '0';`. As the operator precedence here is: `-`, `<<`, `&`, `?:`, `=`.