# C strings behavior, and atoi function

Tags: c, string, atoi, gets

I wonder why the two values of int don't validate the if condition even if it is true.  **printf** shows both of them are equal.

Is buffer overflow able to affect the behavior of if conditions,corrupting other code sections behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

  int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    char instring[2]; // when this increases somehow I get the right behavior
    int inint;
    int guess;
    guess = rand() % 127;
    inint = ~guess;
    printf("%i\n", guess); //testing with printf()
    while (guess != inint) {
      printf("Guess Number\r\n");
      gets(instring);
      inint = atoi(instring);
      printf("%i\n", inint);

      if (inint > guess) {
        printf("%i\n", inint);
        puts("too high");
      } else if (guess > inint) {
        puts("too low");
      } else {
        puts("right");
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: So are you really asking why a string that is too short overflows?

Comment: Don't ever use `gets`! It's a dangerous function which is prone to buffer overflows (which you have) and therefore has been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, or [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) if you're on a POSIX system.

Comment: no , I said I am asking about if condition , why it does not execute , even values are equal , I'm comparing two numbers

Comment: As for *why* you get a buffer overflow, remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* is important, and it needs its own element in the array. Which means a string of two characters needs space for three to include the terminator.

Comment: Buffer overflow leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once you have UB then all discussion about behavior becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Your problems are caused by the buffer overflow

Comment: I uses printf to show me up the the guessed value , same time I do guess the same value and print it , and it prints correctly but if does not execute probably

Comment: but my conditions after getting the real values.

Comment: Fix the buffer overflow first.

Comment: @root Is it possible that your input is UTF-16 ? So you have 2 bytes for a single character. Because of that, you miss to allocate memory for ("\0") null terminator. Since your array is 2 bytes.

Comment: I'm talking about two ints values conditions happens between two ints.

Comment: Weird things happen if you have buffer overflow. First, you need to fix that...

Comment: both [`atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714) and [`gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714) shouldn't be used

Comment: See [What are the functions from the standard library that must/should be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed here.

```
char instring[2];
```

Now let's think about this line.

```
gets(instring);
```

Let's say you type `10` and hit enter. What will go into `instring` is three bytes.

1. `1`
2. `0`
3. A terminating null.

`instring` can only hold *two* bytes, but `gets` will shove (at least) *three* in anyway. That extra byte will overflow into adjacent memory corrupting some other variable's memory causing some bizarre bug.

And that's why making `instring` large enough to hold the result from `gets` fixes the program.

To avoid this when working with strings, use functions which limit themselves to the memory available. In this case [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

```
fgets(instring, sizeof(instring), stdin);
```

That will limit itself to only reading as much as it can fit into `instring`.

In general, don't get stingy with memory to read input. A common practice is to allocate one large buffer for reading input, 1024 is good, and reuse that buffer just for reading input. The data is copied out of it to more appropriately sized memory, which `atoi` effectively does for you.

Comment: so conditions behavior is corrupted with stack overflow ?

Comment: @root Not a stack overflow, that's something different, but a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Probably into `guess`. You can check their memory locations with `printf("%p / %p", &instring, &guess)`.

Comment: Most likely  the values of the int variables declared after the overflowing char array get their values changed.

Comment: @root Note that their order in memory isn't necessarily their order in the program. And it can change from compiler to compiler and even between compiler options. When I compile with `-fsanitize=address` `guess` comes after `instring`. But when I remove that `guess` comes *before* `instring`. Anyhow, a buffer overflow triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and all bets are off.