# gets() function throw exception?

Tags: c, visual-studio, user-input, gets

```
void getInputWith_gets()
{
    char firstName[5];
    char lastName[5];
    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    gets(firstName);
    printf("Enter your last name: ");
    gets(lastName);
    printf("Hello, %s, %s\n", firstName, lastName);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    getInputWith_gets();
    //getInputWith_fgets();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using MS Visual Studio 2017, I know the restriction of using the "gets()" function that I have a maximum of 5 chars to be entered but if I entered exactly 5 characters, the console prints correctly(and doesn't print "press any key to continue... due to "system("pause") statment") but the program get stuck at the debugger screen and after the last "printf" statement I get a a red error symbol with a pop-up saying: 
"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'lastName' was corrupted."
does this means that the "gets()" function will read 5 exclusive characters only?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's a dangerous function, and because of that have been obsoleted since the C99 standard, and removed completely from the latest C11 standard.

Comment: As for your problem, you seem to have forgotten that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* part is important, and of course needs space in your arrays.

Comment: a `char[5]` only has room for a string consisting of max. 4 characters (because it needs room for the `'\0'` terminator)

Comment: I just came from Java background so am just new to C and all I wanted is an explanation for the exception as exceptions in Java are more descriptive

Comment: Then I suggest you get a few books to read from the beginning. And learn that C doesn't *have* exceptions. Unfortunately the underlying operating system and hardware might have what it calls "exceptions" but it's not the same as Java (or C# or C++) exceptions.

Comment: The comments are pretty clear. You try to stuff 6 bytes into a 5 bytes array. A 5 character string takes up 6 bytes (5 for the characters and one for the NUL terminator). In C there is no checking of array bounds at all and there are no exceptions. Google "c undefined behaviour".

Comment: this is what I get when insert more than 5 inclusive characters. This is the exception that I am talking about, and I know that C/C++ has no exception like index out of bound.
https://ibb.co/nmwNzo

Comment: @DesertXGhost "Stack around the variable 'lastName' was corrupted".  Right.  The array is of size 5, but `gets` wrote 5 characters *plus* the trailing null character.  So `gets` wrote beyond where it was supposed to, and that explains the exception.  So the moral of the story is (1) allocate string arrays bigger than they need to be and (2) don't use `gets`.

Comment: In situations like these, it almost never makes sense to say "I want to read a string of exactly 5 characters, so I'll make an array of exactly the right size."  Strings are pretty inherently variable-length.  So if you want to read someone's first name, say "The name will probably be 5 to 10 characters, but some are longer, and I need to remember to leave room for the trailing null character also, so to be on the safe side I'll make it `char firstName[25]`.  Computers these days have lots and lots of memory.  It's been a *long* time since we had to worry about keeping things small.

Comment: What @SteveSummit says: don't bean-count. Unless you are in a RAM-restricted embedded environment, just [128] and be done with.  "don't use gets" - for sure!

Comment: Why not use `scanf` since first/last names (usually) don't contain any blank space characters.

Comment: "exceptions in Java are more descriptive" --> Java is like walking on a tight rope with a net.  C is like walking on a tight rope [without a net](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/1503460312keeping-programming-skills-sharp-1024x475.jpg).  It assumes code is well written and does not need checks.

Comment: @kingW3 It's true that most beginning programmers learn how to do input using `scanf`.  At some point, though, you have to un-learn `scanf`, and learn some more robust techniques for doing input, because `scanf` is basically useless for real programs.  So I'll never discourage someone from starting off on the right foot and doing line-based input from the get-go.  (Although not using `gets`, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple bugs here:

- In ancient, obsolete C where `gets` existed, you must `#include <stdio.h>` or otherwise you might get weird run-time behavior, since ancient obsolete C allowed functions with no prototype.
- In modern and semi-modern C, the function `gets` is removed/flagged obsolete and should never be used. See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) and also [What are the functions from the standard library that must/should be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518).
- Strings in C are null terminated, meaning you have to leave room for the null terminator.

Also note that the function format `void getInputWith_gets()` is obsolete style, you should be writing `void getInputWith_gets(void)`.

Overall, it seems you are learning C from a completely outdated source (over 20 years outdated).

Comment: `void getInputWith_gets()` as part of a function definition as OP did is not obsolete.  As part of a declaration, it is obsolete C11 6.11.6.  IAC, I like the explicit `(void)` in function  definitions too.

Comment: @chux Have you seen anyone writing function declarations as `void getInputWith_gets(void);` but definitions as `void getInputWith_gets()`?. That would be a very strange coding style and code smell.

Comment: Yes I have and it has an odor of higher maintenance - though not obsolete.