# Result of type cast and bitwise operation in C depends on the order

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, bitwise-operators, implicit-conversion, bit-shift

I was trying to print the minimum of `int, char, short, long` without using the header file `<limit.h>`. So bitwise operation will be a good choice. But something strange happened.

The statement

```
printf("The minimum of short: %d\n", ~(((unsigned short)~0) >> 1));
```

gives me

```
The minimum of short: -32768
```

But the statement

```
printf("The minimum of short: %d\n", ~((~(unsigned short)0) >> 1));
```

gives me

```
The minimum of short: 0
```

This phenomenon also occurs in `char`. But it does not occur in `long, int`. Why does this happen?

And it is worth mentioning that I use VS Code as my editor. When I moved my cursor on `unsigned char` in the statement

```
printf("The minimum of char: %d\n", (short)~((~(unsigned char)0) >> 1));
```

It gives me a hint `(int) 0` instead of `(unsigned char)0`, which I expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: @Lundin misunderstood the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `limit.h` - this is exactly the reason that header file exists in the Standard Library?!

Comment: @Andrew I am reading the book K&R2(The C Programming Language). And printing the maximum and minimum of `int, long, short, char` is an exercise of it. However, the solution manual(The C Answer book) gives two solutions and one of them is using `limit.h`. But the other is about bitwise operation. So I get interested and gave it a shot. Never thought this would be a pigfall.

Comment: Fair enough - but note, K&R2 is 20 years old, so not an ideal tutorial for modern C (with the greatest respect to Messrs K&R)

Comment: @Andrew: Personally I don't subscribe to that idea. It's an excellent tutorial for C. Read it first, do the example exercises, then, by all means, read a good book covering C11.

Comment: @Andrew I am still a beginner of C. Could you please recommend an ideal tutorial for modern C?

Comment: @Bathsheba - fair point... but you also MUST understand what has changed since - not least with the standardisation of the language.  There are plenty of more modern text books and tutorials (including online).

Comment: @Andrew: Perhaps this is a misjudgement and I'm not a C expert, but methinks that reading K & R, and completing all the example exercises, sets you up with the ability to answer the vast majority of the C questions that pop up on this site. To me that says something about the book. I haven't come across a book that relays topics like pointer arithmetic, string library functions, and complex declarations more thoroughly.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to avoid K&R. It is sloppily written with too many small mistakes, it is teaching reliance on poorly-specified behavior and it uses horrible coding style (squeeze as many operators as possible into a single line etc). The 2nd edition has not been updated properly to cover ISO C90, there's various mistakes here and there remaining from pre-standard times. And of course it does not address C99 nor C11. And so you can play "find the errors" on almost every page in it.

Comment: @Lundin : do you have some example of such errors?

Comment: @schaiba The operator precedence table for one. And as I said, you can take pretty such any page and find some sort of error. Anyway, I think all these comments have derailed quite a bit off the topic.

Comment: This is off-topic, but for anyone reading this far, I must state a contrasting opinion.  K&R is an *excellent* book.  I believe it taught me more about programming than all others combined.  Parts of it are indeed dated by now, but to call it "sloppily written" is a pretty grave insult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, none of your code is really reliable and won't do what you expect.

`printf` and all other variable argument length functions have a dysfunctional "feature" called *the default argument promotions*. This means that the actual type of the parameters passed undergo silent promotion. Small integer types (such as `char` and `short`) get promoted to `int` which is signed. (And float gets promoted to double.)  Tl;dr: `printf` is a nuts function.

Therefore you can cast between various small integer types all you want, there will still be a promotion to `int` in the end. This is no problem if you use the correct format specifier for the intended type, but you don't, you use `%d` which is for `int`.

In addition, the `~` operator, like most operators in C, performs implicit integer promotion of its operand. See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

---

That being said, this line `~((~(unsigned short)0) >> 1)` does the following:

- Take the literal `0` which is of type `int` and convert to `unsigned short`.
- Implicitly promote that `unsigned short` back to `int` through implicit integer promotion.
- Calculate the bitwise complement of the `int` value `0`. This is `0xFF...FF` hex, `-1` dec, assuming 2's complement.
- Right shift this `int` by 1. Here you invoke implementation-defined behavior upon shifting a negative integer. C allows this to either result in a logical shift = shift in zeroes, or arithmetic shift = shift in a sign bit. Different result from compiler to compiler and non-portable.

  You get either `0x7F...FF` in case of logical shift or `0xFF...FF` in case of arithmetic shift. In this case it seems to be the latter, meaning you still have decimal `-1` after shift.
- You do bitwise complement of the `0xFF...FF` = `-1` and get `0`.
- You cast this to `short`. Still `0`.
- Default argument promotion convert it to `int`. Still `0`.
- `%d` expects a `int` and therefore prints accordingly. `unsigned short` is printed with `%hu` and `short` with `%hd`. Using the correct format specifier should undo the effect of default argument promotion.

Advice: study implicit type promotion and avoid using bitwise operators on operands that have signed type.

To simply display the lowest 2's complement value of various signed types, you have to do some trickery with unsigned types, since bitwise operations on their signed version are unreliable. Example:

```
int shift = sizeof(short)*8 - 1;  // 15 bits on sane systems
short s = (short) (1u << shift);
printf("%hd\n", s);
```

This shifts an unsigned int `1u` 15 bits, then converts the result of that to short, in some "implementation-defined way", meaning on two's complement systems you'll end up converting 0x8000 to -32768.

Then give `printf` the right format specifier and you'll get the expected result from there.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: This is an excellent answer, but ultimately brittle. Read it well, but don't overthink it. The fact remains that you *can't* compute the minimum value of signed integral types portably in C. Note too that in 2's complement systems you'll find the minimum values defined in the form -MAX - 1 to obviate unwanted type promotion.

Comment: Fixed. Printing the lowest decimal value in a safe and portable manner is indeed a bit tricky.

Comment: @Bathsheba You can compute it portably, kind of. I added an example. The only non-portable aspect is the conversion from unsigned int to short, which is implementation-defined. But the only things that are implementation-defined about it is the size of integers, the fact that C allows dysfunctional signed formats like 1's complement and signed magnitude, and thereby also padding bits, traps and other such nonsense. But given that short is 16 bits and the system is 2's complement, the above code should behave deterministically.

Comment: @Lundin Who says a char is 8 bit? `sizeof(short)*8` is not always the number of bits of a short . The sizeof() operator returns the size in number of chars and some systems have 16 bit chars for example. In which case sizeof(short) would most likely return 1. There is no way around CHAR_BIT as defined in limits.h and then you can just use the rest of the defines there too.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Hence the comment `// 15 bits on sane systems`. Insane systems are not supported by this code, though feel free to add `_Static_assert(CHAR_BIT==8, "Insane architectures not supported.");`. People who are concerned about portability to exotic DSP:s are just wasting everyone's time. It's kind of like building a parking garage and taking into account that a monster truck might want to park there.

Comment: People who are concerned about portability use limits.h because it's there for a reason.

Comment: @Lundin `printf` has its warts, no question, but it's one of the core parts of C.  There's absolutely no replacement for it.  If you hate `printf`, you hate C.  But you should love your tools.  May I humbly suggest you either find another language you like better, or take it a little easier on C, which despite its warts has been wildly successful?

Comment: @SteveSummit Or could it be that I work with embedded systems and thus get to use C without the horrible stdio.h anywhere in sight? There's a whole lot of  reasons why that library is banned in most professional coding standards. Believe me, the success of C has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with stdio.h. The key to becoming a good C programmer is otherwise to understand and accept that the language is terribly flawed, and from there learn all the flaws, since most of them are well-known.

Comment: [Here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518) regarding which functions in the standard library one should use with caution.