# Why do I get a segfault with atoi in c?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, atoi

I'm trying to read a string from argv. It should be something like a mathematical function like `"-x^2-5"` etc.

I've got something like this:

```
void test(char *function){
  int temp = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(function); i++){
    if((function[i] != '+') && (function[i] != ...){
      // function[i] is a digit, but still as a char
      temp = atoi(function[i]);
    }
  }
  //... 
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  test(argv[1]);
  //...
}
```

This works quite well until the last lap of the loop.
If I use `printf("%c", function[i]);`, it sais, it's `5`.

But `atoi(function[i])` gives a segfault. Why?

Comment: Please test `if(argc >= 2)` before using `argv[1]`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings!  `function[i]` is a single `char`, not a `char*`.  As such, it is implicitly cast to a pointer type and `atoi` tries to read from a near-zero memory address.  Perhaps you meant `&function[i]` or `function + i`

Comment: `atoi(function[i])` is actually not valid C, so whatever compiler let this code through is bad. Be aware that most of the mainstream C compilers come in "bad mode" by default. You have to add `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` to turn them into C compilers. Also see [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. Let's first take a look at the signature of `atoi`.

```c
int atoi(const char *str);
```

Now, what you are passing to it is `function[i]`, and since `function` is of type `char *`, `function[i]` is a `char`. And your character is most likely not a proper character pointer.

What you'd want to pass to `atoi` is instead a `const char *`, which you can get by calling `atoi(&function[i]);`

Comment: @xXxKaddiexXx Although if I were trying to parse expressions like that, I'd look into doing "proper" lexical analysis of the expression, and then using something like the "shunting yard" algorithm to create an expression tree out of the user-provided expression. Makes it easier to recognize whether a symbol is an operator, a variable like x, or a literal value like 2. Also makes it easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

As already said by @sham1, `atoi` expects its parameter to be a C string, this is a null terminated char array, while you have a single char.

But digits are special, because they are required to have consecutive codes. So if you know that a character (say `c`) is a digit, its value is `c - '0'`. So you can write:

```
if((function[i] != '+') && (function[i] != ...){
  // function[i] is a digit, but still as a char
  temp = function[i] - '0';    // get the int value of a digit character
}
```

Comment: actually this didn't work in my case. I'm not sure, whether I missed something important in my code example above.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the bug pointed out in other answers, `atoi` doesn't have any reliable error handling, which is why it is one of the [standard library functions that should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518).

Just forget that you ever heard about `atoi` and replace it with:

```
char* endptr;
int result = strtol(str,&endptr,10);

if(endptr == str)
{
  // some conversion error
}
```

`strtol` is also able to convert an initial part of the string if it contains valid numbers.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't know that. That would have saved a lot of time xD. Thank you :)

Comment: @xXxKaddiexXx In this specific case, you are essentially providing something that is not a null-terminated string, so `strtol` wouldn't likely have been able to find this problem either.