# character array filling

Tags: c, file-io

I want to declare character array and later want to fill it. But getting error:

```
char line[BUFSIZE+1];
strcpy(line,"Memory is Full", sizeof(line));
```

Error is:

```
wrong number of arguments in call to strcpy.
```

Is there any alternative to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy()` takes 2 arguments, `strncpy()` takes 3.

I think you were thinking about using [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/), that takes destination, source, and size.

ie:

```
int main()
{
    char i[6];
    strncpy(i, "Hello", sizeof(i));
    printf("%s\n", i);    
    return 0;
}

>> ./a.out
>> Hello
```

**Note:** You have to append the `'\0'` yourself if you completly fill your char[], otherwise `strncpy()` will do it for you (as in my example).

Comment: But strncpy is a problematic, strange function. I wouldn't advise anyone to use it, memcpy() is a much safer and faster function.

Comment: @Lundin What are the problems with strncpy?

Comment: In this case, problem with strncpy is that there is no guarantee the string is null-terminated. if BUFSIZE = 5, then line will contain 'Memory' and all other string functions will overrun the end of the string.

Comment: @mcl - It just comes down to RTFM. It's clear everywhere, the man page for `strncpy()` even has a bold "warning" printed in it

Comment: @Mike, sorry I meant to respond only to simonc's question, not criticize your answer! I personally love `strncpy`, but Sijith's code needs to guard carefully against the length issue. Same problem applies if he uses `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

Comment: @simonc Google for "problems with strncpy", "don't use strncpy", "strncpy seg fault" or find any debate about it on this site. There was one yesterday..

Comment: @Mike It's clear everywhere but in the standard: `If the array pointed to by s2 is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been written.` They forgot to add: if the array pointed to by s2 >= n characters long, strncpy will cause your program to crash and burn.

Comment: @simonc: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115015/166749) (which is actually about `strlcpy`, but discusses `strncpy` as well).

Comment: @Lundin - hmm, good point. Well, I covered it in this instance with my footnote, and a number of sources (apparently not everywhere though) do note the fact that the last null is missing when `s2 > n`

Comment: @Mike If you have to append '\0' manually, I think you are better off using memcpy() instead. The link posted by larsmans provides a very nice explanation of why strncpy is such a weird function: it was never intended to be a safe version of strcpy, it is merely a special-purpose function suitable for string types in ancient Unix systems. So unless you are writing code for an ancient Unix system, you should probably think twice before using strncpy.

Comment: @Lundin - Doesn't memcpy have the same issue? If I `memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest))` and `src` is longer than `dest` you're still going to end up having to append the null yourself. I do agree about larsmans explanation and the `strlcpy` sounds like a good function. But as far as memcpy vs. strncpy, seems like a wash to me.

Comment: @Mike memcpy only does what you tell it to do. strncpy on the other hand, is looking for null terminations, and it may or may not append null terminations at the end, depending on whether you passed string length or buffer length, or something else. And it doesn't just add 1 null termination, it adds as many as it can.

Answer (score 3):

If you have it, use `strlcpy()`. It does what you might expect `strncpy()` to do.

Failing that, I would recommend using `snprintf()`, if you have it.

Comment: +1 for `snprintf` and `strlcpy`, but the latter is available only in BSD C libraries (and Solaris, IIRC, or was it AIX).

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` doesn't take a size/length argument. Use `memcpy` instead, but give it the size (length+1) of the string being copied, not the size of the buffer, or you risk undefined behavior/segfaults.