# Cut characters for a string in C

Tags: c, string, cut

Here's some code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char npass[] = "$1$bUZXMjKz$08Ps4NPTfj6ZNkoqrsP/D.";
    char salt [12];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
            npass[i+3] = salt[i];
            i++;
    }
    salt[12] = '\0';
    puts(salt);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, *npass* is an `md5crypt` result(password is admin). In order to verify this, I need to separate the salt from the result.

My understanding is that a string in `C` is really a `char array` containing all the letters alone(with `'\0'` at the end). I use a `for` loop to cut the first three characters but I guess because of `ASLR`, the results that I get are always random ones. Actually, *without* `ASLR`, I get the same random result always.

Comment: `salt[12] = '\0';` is UB, since `salt` is only 12 bytes long.

Comment: You're incrementing `i` both inside the for loop and as a `for` statement parameter. You want one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you get "random" data, you assign *to* the hash and not the salt. You want the other way around:

```
salt[i] = npass[i+3];
```

Or you could skip the loop and do:

```
memcpy(salt, npass + 3, sizeof(salt) - 1);
salt[sizeof(salt) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: It would be better and safer to use memcpy. strncpy is an old, dangerous, mainly obsolete function intended for ancient unix code. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure).

Comment: Your code produced 1 character less than I wanted so I removed the `- 1` in both lines. Worked beautifully after that. Thank you.

Comment: @Mangix No, don't remove the `-1` or you will overwrite beyond the end of the `salt` array. Instead increase the size of the `salt` array by one.

Answer (score 0):

With all bugs already pointed out, and some aesthetic fixes, you should end up with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SALT_N 12

int main()
{
    const char npass[] = "$1$bUZXMjKz$08Ps4NPTfj6ZNkoqrsP/D.";
    char salt [SALT_N+1];

    memcpy(salt, npass, SALT_N);
    salt[SALT_N] = '\0';
    puts(salt);
    return 0;
}
```