# C programming: how to fill an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I know strncpy(s1, s2, n) copies n elements of s2 into s1, but that only fills it from the beginning of s1.
For example

```
s1[10] = "Teacher"
s2[20] = "Assisstant"
strncpy(s1, s2, 2) would yield s1[10] = "As", correct?
```

Now what if I want s1 to contain "TeacherAs"? How would I do that? Is strncpy the appropriate thing to use in this case?

Comment: Were the top two meant to be declarations?

Comment: No: `strncpy(s1, s2, 2)` would cause s1[] to contain "Asacher". Remember: strncpy() is evil.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) to concatenate strings, however you don't want all of the source string copied in this case, so you need to use something like:

```
size_t len = strlen(s1);
strncpy(s1 + len - 1, s2, 2);
s2[len + 2] = '\0';
```

(Add terminating nul; thanks @FatalError).

Which is pretty horrible and you need to worry about the amount of space remaining in the destination array.  Please note that if `s1` is empty that code will break!

There is `strncat()` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat)) under some systems, which is much simpler to use:

```
strncat(s1, s2, 2);
```

Comment: What about the terminating nul?

Comment: @FatalError that will be included in size of s1.

Comment: @Arpit No I don't think it will; only if s2 is shorter than 2, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: @FatalError Thanks; hopefully fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Use [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

Make sure your string you're appending to is big enough to hold both strings. In your case it isn't.

From the link above:
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );

Concatenate strings
Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

destination and source shall not overlap.

Comment: Wouldn't that give "TeacherAssistant" and not "TeacherAs"? Plus the buffer size is a concern if that `[10]` was supposed to be for a declaration.

Comment: no it will not. you need to make sure there is enough space in destination for the resulting string. additionally, this would cat TeacherAssistant in full

Comment: dang @FatalError beat me by a second!

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you need you have to use [`strlcat`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcat/) (but beware! it is [considered insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure))

```
strlcat(s1, s2, sizeof(s1));
```

This will concatenate to `s1`, part of the `s2` string, until the size of `s1` is reached (this avoids `memory overflow`)

then you'll get into `s1` the string `TeacherAs` + a NUL char to terminate it

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that you have enough memory is allocated for the resulting string

```
s1[10]
```

is not enough space to fit 'TeacherAs'.

from there, you'll want to do something like

```
//make sure s1 is big enough to hold s1+s2
s1[40]="Teacher";
s2[20]="Assistant";

//how many chars from second string you want to append
int offset = 2;
//allocate a temp buffer 
char subbuff[20];
//copy n chars to buffer
memcpy( subbuff, s2, offset );
//null terminate buff
subbuff[offset+1]='\0';

//do the actual cat
strcat(s1,subbuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `snprintf()`, like:

```
size_t len = strlen(s1);
snprintf(s1 + len, sizeof(s1) - len, "%.2s", s2);
```

`snprintf()` will always nul terminate and won't overrun your buffer. Plus, it's standard as of C99. As a note, this assumes that `s1` is an array declared in the current scope so that `sizeof` works, otherwise you'll need to provide the size.