# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'char [5]'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'char [5]'
help me)

```
    char type[5];
    switch (rec[n-1].recptr->qtype)
    {
        case 'p':type='pcs'; break; //here is problem
        case 'm':type='kgs'; break; // and here is too
        default: printf("incorrect code");break;
    }
```

Comment: You can't do it like that even with the right type of literal. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Well, depending on whether this is C or C++, std::string may not be an option.

Comment: `'pcs'` is a multi-character character constant, which has an implementation-defined value of type `int`. It's a language feature that's very rarely useful, but it can produce confusing error messages (or no error messages at all if you're particularly unlucky).

Comment: @Inisheer, If it's tagged C++, I feel free to use C++ in my responses. If the OP doesn't want C++, they shouldn't tag it as such, just like it isn't tagged Java, Python, C#, Ruby, or any other language they don't want.

Comment: @chris Yup, agree. Just pointing it out in the event the OP wanted to use your comment while using C.

Answer (score 5):

First, strings go in double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`. Second, to assign to a `char[]` array you must use a function like [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). You can't assign directly to an array with `=`.

```
case 'p': strcpy(type, "pcs"); break;
case 'm': strcpy(type, "kgs"); break;
```

Comment: @cf16: No, `strncpy` is *not* for strings.

Comment: @cf16: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure (although it is sometimes used with strings, it is a bad idea).

Comment: ok, it might not null terminate, one should be aware of this, but for sure not strcpy in the form above!

Comment: @cf16 `type` has room for five characters. These strings will occupy four (three chars + NUL). There is no danger.

Comment: this is always some vulnerability

Comment: if you find some way to interrupt strcpy and change strings that are to be copied then you are stuck, strncpy will not allow for this

Comment: @cf16: Keith Thompson pretty much destroys the argument that `strncpy` is a *string* function [here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).  It's for dealing with fixed-size arrays of `char`, which are not necessarily strings.  It is most definitely *not* a safer version of `strcpy`, and should not be used as such.

Comment: @JohnBode really this is funny that paper: use strncpy as it is supposed to be used and this is really safe version of strcpy

Answer (score 4):

First, `'pcs'` is a character constant, whereas you want a string. The syntax is `"pcs"`.

Moreover, `type` is an array, so when it is not used with `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or unary `&` operator, it decays to a pointer, and it is **not** an lvalue. Therefore you cannot re-assign `type`.

`strcpy` could be a solution.

```
#include <string.h>

char type[5];

switch (rec[n-1].recptr->qtype)
{
    case 'p':
        strcpy(type,"pcs"); 
        break;
    case 'm':
        strcpy(type,"kgs"); 
        break;
    default: 
        printf("incorrect code");
        break;
}
```

Or, using string litterals (if you don't modify `type`):

```
const char *type;
switch (rec[n-1].recptr->qtype)
{
    case 'p':
        type="pcs"; 
        break;
    case 'm':
        type="kgs"; 
        break;
    default: 
        printf("incorrect code");
        break;
}
```

### References

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
>   operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>                  to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

`'pcs'` is a multi-character literal of type `int`.

`type` is an array. You cannot assign anything to an entire array with `=`.

[Technically speaking, in that expression `type` behaves as non-modifiable pointer pointing to the first element of the array, but you can't modify a non-modifiable value.]

Comment: `'pcs'` is of type `int` in C++ also.

Comment: @ouah But `'p'` is `char` in C++, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use strcpy(type, "pcs") and strcpy(type, "kgs") or std:string, you cant copy character in array simply by assigning!

Answer (score 0):

please use strcpy , you cannot assign to char[5] with =

```
case 'p': strcpy(type, "pcs"); break;
```

but if you want to avoid strcpy (even in such theoretically safe case) you can do it also this way:

```
  /* partial copy (only 3 chars): */
  strncpy ( type, "pcs", 3 );
  type[4] = '\0';   /* null character manually added */
```

Comment: You have to be very careful with `strncpy()`. It will not null terminate if it truncates.

Comment: I have changed though i have to check this

Comment: @FredLarson if you use string larger than buffer in vase of strcpy you are really out of luck but in case of strncpy it will be handled in safe way: what is better is obvious

Comment: From [one man page reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy): "Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated." This would also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Of course, `strcpy()` does not have a problem with null termination. It has a problem with potential buffer overruns. It's hard to win with C string manipulation. Null termination, buffer overruns, [Schlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html), etc. Lots of ways to get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep to sizeof(int) characters or less, you can do something like the following:

```
int type;
switch (rec[n-1].recptr->qtype)
{
    case 'p':type='pcs'; break; //here is problem
    case 'm':type='kgs'; break; // and here is too
    default: printf("incorrect code");break;
}
```

above code not tested, although I did test this:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    int t;
    t = 'abcd';
    printf ("t = %x\n", t);
    t = 'dcba';
    printf ("t = %x\n", t);
}

[347] ~/tmp: ./a.out
t = 61626364
t = 64636261
```

You really have to be careful here though that you don't use > sizeof(int) characters here.  I suspect mileage may vary per compiler on what actually happens.  Using this method gets rid of all the extra string worries that are floating around in other answers.