# Allocating a 2D array of characters

Tags: c

I am making a program to allocate a 20x20 array of characters. Here is what I did:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char *a=(char*) calloc(20,sizeof(char[20]));
a[0]="abcd";
printf("%s\n",a[0]);
return 0;
}
```

[Link to ideone](http://ideone.com/lKE5sa).

The output of the above code is `(null)`. Can anybody please explain this? According to me, I am allocating a pointer `a` 20 spaces of size 20 each. So `a[0]` technically has enough memory to store "abcd", yet the output is `null`.

Comment: This code doesn't really compile.  Enable compiler warnings: http://ideone.com/exEpiH.

Comment: ignore the warning, I got a ``segmentation fault``. I use g++ 4.7

Comment: The string literal `"abcd"` was incidentally placed at a location whose address was a multiple of 256 is the most likely scenario.

Comment: why have you compiled the code in C99 strict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of variable `a` that you have is incorrect: it should be `char (*a)[20]` (yes, with parentheses).

This line is also incorrect:

```
a[0]="abcd";
```

you cannot assign C strings like that, because `a[0]` is not a pointer: it is an array of 20 characters, so you need to use `strcpy` instead:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char (*a)[20]=calloc(20, sizeof(char[20]));
    strcpy(a[0], "abcd");
    strcpy(a[1], "wxyz");
    printf("%s\n",a[0]);
    printf("%s\n",a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

See the corrected program running [here](http://ideone.com/xHx3Di).

Note: Unlike C++, C does not require type casting of `void` pointers. It is typical for C programs to omit the cast of results returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`, because the type is already known from the type of the variable being assigned.

Comment: No. Don't use strcpy. ever. Use std::string. At the very worst, use strncpy.

Comment: `strncpy(from, destination, count)` is better than `strcpy(from, destination)` to prevent buffer overflow

Comment: @SecurityMatt `std::string` is C++, this question is tagged as `C`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Then use strncpy. That's why I listed both. strcpy is always a bad choice, whether you're in C or C++.

Comment: @Kevin `strncpy` is one of the most misunderstood functions in the C library. It is designed for using with strings of fixed length, not for preventing overruns.

Comment: @SecurityMatt See my comment addressed to Kevin: `strncpy` is not for preventing memory overruns, it's for working with strings of fixed length.

Comment: I was trying to implement this as something related to vector< vector<int> > , like I did in graphs, that is allocating a  array of char pointers storing pointers to an array of chars , so I modified my code http://ideone.com/gNdIXo , and it works fine.

Comment: @DrefD It's still incorrect: if you need an array of pointers, it would look like [this](http://ideone.com/5BQKeM). Currently, you allocate more memory than you need - 20 bytes per pointer, instead of `sizeof(char*)` per pointer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , well the purpose of my question was not exactly for memory allocation , but to instead look for another way of declaring a 2D array of chars. Since the usual method:  char**a= calloc(m,sizeof(char*); for(i=0;i<m;i++) a[i]=calloc(m,sizeof(char)); has been used by me quite often , so i wanted to explore another way of declaring 2D array dynamically. So is my method correct?

Comment: @DrefD Allocating a 2D array would look like [this](http://ideone.com/0yzclE). Since it's a 2D array of chars, not a 1D array of pointers, you're back to `strcpy` land.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for an adjacency matrix representation! Thanks @dasblinkenlight , but you mentioned typecasting not being necessary in C, can you please throw some light on this !

Comment: @DrefD Please see the edit to the answer. Now that I understand what you are trying to do, it's much easier to explain what's wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: WTF are you talking about? strncpy is exactly for preventing buffer overruns. That's why strcpy is not suitable for secure development, but strncpy is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy. Why it was introduced is irrelevant. The fact is that strncpy's primary use today is to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Based on this `OWASP` post - `https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Code_for_Buffer_Overruns_and_Overflows`, why doesn't `strncpy()` guard against buffer overflows?

Comment: @SecurityMatt There is a broad confusion about the purpose of `strncpy`. I don't think I can explain it better than AndreyT did in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115015/335858), though.

Comment: @Kevin See the link to an answer in my comment above. Long story short, `strncpy` does not guard against buffer overflows because it does not null-terminate strings which are longer than the desired length. You need to add `str[len-1]='\0'`, the way the OWASP people did in their example. This is error-prone. That's why there's `strlcpy` function fits in.