# How to copy a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, copy

In C, I have two char arrays:

```
char array1[18] = "abcdefg";
char array2[18];
```

How to copy the value of `array1` to `array2` ? Can I just do this: `array2 = array1`?

Comment: `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

Comment: `char array1[18] = {"abcdefg"};` is not a proper char array.

Comment: Use strcpy(array2,array1)  function

Comment: Do you wish to copy the "string" of it (until the "\0") and ignore the rest? or do you wish to copy all the array (18 chars) regardless of the content?

Comment: While it does work as char array (just happens to work) it should either be declared as `char array1[18] = "abcdefg";` or `char array1[18] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};`

Comment: @aragaer 6.7.9 (14): "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, **optionally enclosed in braces**." `char array1[18] = {"abcdefg"};` is unusual, but 100% pukka.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh. Never seen that myself. Also in my book (KR in russian) there's no mention about optional braces for that kind of initialization.

Comment: but can we do the initialiation of char array like this:char array1[18] = "abcdefg";?

Comment: Does memcpy(..) handles the memory (I mean maloc and realoc inside it)?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can't directly do `array2 = array1`, because in this case you manipulate the addresses of the arrays (`char *`) and not of their inner values (`char`).

What you, conceptually, want is to do is iterate through all the chars of your source (*array1*) and copy them to the destination (*array2*). There are several ways to do this. For example you could write a simple for loop, or  use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy).

That being said, the recommended way for strings is to use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy). It prevents common errors resulting in, for example, [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (which is especially dangerous if `array1` is filled from user input: keyboard, network, etc). Like so:

```
// Will copy 18 characters from array1 to array2
strncpy(array2, array1, 18);
```

As @Prof. Falken mentioned in a comment, `strncpy` [can be evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2004/11/02/251296.aspx). Make sure your target buffer is big enough to contain the source buffer (including the `\0` at the end of the string).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2004/11/02/251296.aspx  strncpy() is actually evil too. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure

Comment: why we can not just do array2 = array1?

Comment: @user2131316: This is because of the way array names are semantically converted into pointer values. I explain this in my answer.

Comment: It confused me that you mention `array1=array2`, which implies that array1 gets the new value, but your code does it the other way round. Just in case anybody else falls for this.

Comment: strncat would always provide a nul-terminated result without buffer overrun. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/4123703).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for particularly the extra 1 char buffer to contain the /0

Answer (score 46):

If your arrays are not string arrays, use:
`memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof(array2));`

Comment: Wouldn't sizeof() return the size of the pointer (i.e. the word size on your machine) ?

Comment: @Wecherowski: When you pass an array to a function, it degrades to a pointer. Within that function, you cannot use `sizeof()` to determin the size of the array then. Otherwise `sizeof()` works fine for that task.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to guard against non-terminated strings, which can cause all sorts of problems, copy your string like this:

```
char array1[18] = {"abcdefg"};
char array2[18];

size_t destination_size = sizeof (array2);

strncpy(array2, array1, destination_size);
array2[destination_size - 1] = '\0';
```

That last line is actually important, because `strncpy()` does not always [null terminate](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR32-C.+Null-terminate+byte+strings+as+required) strings. (If the destination buffer is too small to contain the whole source string, sntrcpy() will not null terminate the destination string.)

The manpage for strncpy() even states *"Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated."*

The reason strncpy() behaves this somewhat odd way, is because it was not actually originally intended as a safe way to copy strings.

Another way is to use snprintf() as a safe replacement for strcpy():

```
snprintf(array2, destination_size, "%s", array1);
```

<sub>(Thanks [jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/jxh) for the tip.)</sub>

Comment: Note that `snprintf()` does not have the problem that `strncpy()` does.

Comment: Does't this generate a warning? strncpy accepts const char as source.

Comment: @konpsych that should not generate a warning.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Are there reasons to use one vs. the other?

Comment: @Rahav, *snprintf()* is easier to use correctly than *strncpy()*

Comment: Do you expect meaningful performance differences?

Comment: @Rahav, impossible to tell without testing, but *a)* these operation are fast on modern hardware anyway. *b)* for very tiny strings maybe strncpy() could be faster, for larger strings the actual copying in memory will dominate time taken and both should be about the same in speed is my guess. Todays compilers and libraries are also incredible at optimising and what used to be hard to guess, is now very very hard to guess. Just measure / profile if you want to be sure. In actual use there will almost never be a meaningful difference is my best guess.

Answer (score 12):

As others have noted, strings are copied with `strcpy()` or its variants. In certain cases, you could use `snprintf()` as well.

You can only assign arrays the way you want as part of a structure assignment:

```
typedef struct { char a[18]; } array;
array array1 = { "abcdefg" };
array array2;

array2 = array1;
```

If your arrays are passed to a function, it will appear that you are allowed to assign them, but this is just an accident of the semantics. In C, an array will decay to a pointer type with the value of the address of the first member of the array, and this pointer is what gets passed. So, your array parameter in your function is really just a pointer. The assignment is just a pointer assignment:

```
void foo (char x[10], char y[10]) {
    x = y;    /* pointer assignment! */
    puts(x);
}
```

The array itself remains unchanged after returning from the function.

This "decay to pointer value" semantic for arrays is the reason that the assignment doesn't work. The l-value has the array type, but the r-value is the decayed pointer type, so the assignment is between incompatible types.

```
char array1[18] = "abcdefg";
char array2[18];
array2 = array1; /* fails because array1 becomes a pointer type,
                    but array2 is still an array type */
```

As to why the "decay to pointer value" semantic was introduced, this was to achieve a source code compatibility with the predecessor of C. You can read *[The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)* for details.

Comment: The only answer that explains why `array2 = array1;` does not work. Upvote.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot assign arrays, the names are constants that cannot be changed.

You can copy the *contents*, with:

```
strcpy(array2, array1);
```

assuming the source is a valid string and that the destination is large enough, as in your example.

Answer (score 4):

it should look like this:

```
void cstringcpy(char *src, char * dest)
{
    while (*src) {
        *(dest++) = *(src++);
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
.....

char src[6] = "Hello";
char dest[6];
cstringcpy(src, dest);
```

Comment: Your `cstringcpy` function does not null terminate the destination array.

Comment: didnt get it. please provide your "fix".

Comment: @zett42: note that this `cstringcpy` function is almost exactly semantically equivalent to `strcpy`, with the same shortcomings, namely no check for buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use memcpy() for copying data.
Also if we assign a buffer to another as `array2 = array1` , both array have same memory and any change in the arrary1 deflects in array2 too.  But we use memcpy, both buffer have different array. I recommend memcpy() because strcpy and related function do not copy NULL character.

Answer (score 1):

```
array2 = array1;
```

is not supported in c. You have to use functions like [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/?kw=strcpy) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

c functions below only ... c++ you have to do char array then use a string copy then user the string tokenizor functions... c++ made it a-lot harder to do anythng

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int Bool;
using namespace std;
Bool PalTrueFalse(char str[]);
int main(void)
{
char string[1000], ch;
int i = 0;
cout<<"Enter a message: ";

while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') //grab users input string untill 
{                               //Enter is pressed
    if (!isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch)) //Cstring functions checking for
    {                                //spaces and punctuations of all kinds
        string[i] = tolower(ch); 
        i++;
    }
}
string[i] = '\0';  //hitting null deliminator once users input
cout<<"Your string: "<<string<<endl; 
if(PalTrueFalse(string)) //the string[i] user input is passed after
                        //being cleaned into the null function.
    cout<<"is a "<<"Palindrome\n"<<endl;
else
   cout<<"Not a palindrome\n"<<endl;
return 0;
}

Bool PalTrueFalse(char str[])
{
int left = 0;
int right = strlen(str)-1;
while (left<right)
{
   if(str[left] != str[right]) //comparing most outer values of string
       return FALSE;          //to inner values.
   left++;
   right--;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, techincally you can…

```c
typedef struct { char xx[18]; } arr_wrap;

char array1[18] = "abcdefg";
char array2[18];

*((arr_wrap *) array2) = *((arr_wrap *) array1);

printf("%s\n", array2);     /* "abcdefg" */
```

but it will not look very beautiful.

…Unless you use the C preprocessor…

```c
#define CC_MEMCPY(DESTARR, SRCARR, ARRSIZE) \
    { struct _tmparrwrap_ { char xx[ARRSIZE]; }; *((struct _tmparrwrap_ *) DESTARR) = *((struct _tmparrwrap_ *) SRCARR); }
```

You can then do:

```c
char array1[18] = "abcdefg";
char array2[18];

CC_MEMCPY(array2, array1, sizeof(array1));

printf("%s\n", array2);     /* "abcdefg" */
```

And it will work with any data type, not just `char`:

```c
int numbers1[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int numbers2[3];

CC_MEMCPY(numbers2, numbers1, sizeof(numbers1));

printf("%d - %d - %d\n", numbers2[0], numbers2[1], numbers2[2]);     /* "abcdefg" */
```

(Yes, the code above is [granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578631/is-pointer-to-struct-a-pointer-to-its-first-member) to work always and it's portable)

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

for integer types

```
#include <string.h>    

int array1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int array2[10];


memcpy(array2,array1,sizeof(array1)); // memcpy("destination","source","size")
```

Comment: That won't compile. Use `int array1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign arrays to copy them. How you can copy the contents of one into another depends on multiple factors:

For `char` arrays, if you know the source array is null terminated and destination array is large enough for the string in the source array, including the null terminator, use `strcpy()`:

```
#include <string.h>

char array1[18] = "abcdefg";
char array2[18];

...

strcpy(array2, array1);
```

If you do not know if the destination array is large enough, but the source is a C string, and you want the destination to be a proper C string, use `snprinf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char array1[] = "a longer string that might not fit";
char array2[18];

...

snprintf(array2, sizeof array2, "%s", array1);
```

If the source array is not necessarily null terminated, but you know both arrays have the same size, you can use `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

char array1[28] = "a non null terminated string";
char array2[28];

...

memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above was working for me..
this works perfectly
`name` here is `char *name` which is passed via the function

1. get length of `char *name` using `strlen(name)`
2. storing it in a const variable is important
3. create same length size `char` array
4. copy `name` 's content to `temp` using `strcpy(temp, name);`

use however you want, if you want original content back. `strcpy(name, temp);` copy temp back to `name` and voila works perfectly

```
    const int size = strlen(name);
    char temp[size];
    cout << size << endl;
    strcpy(temp, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy directly by writing `array2 = array1`.

If you want to copy it **manually**, iterate over `array1` and copy item by item as follows -

```
int i;
for(i=0;array1[i]!='\0';i++){
 array2[i] = array1[i]; 
}
array2[i]='\0'; //put the string terminator too
```

If you are ok to use **string library**, you can do it as follows -

```
strncpy ( array2, array1, sizeof(array2) );
```