# How to copy contents in an array of object into another array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, class, object

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class bank
{
public: char name[20];
public: float balance;
public: void get()
{
    cout << "\nEnter name and balance in Account respectively\n";
    cin >> name >> balance;
}
public: void display()
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << "    Balance: " << balance;
}
};
void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    bank b[10];
    bank max;
    bank temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        b[i].get();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (b[i + 1].balance > b[i].balance)
        {
            max.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            max.name = b[i + 1].name;//Error 1 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
        }
        else
        {
            temp.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            temp.name = b[i + 1].name;//Error 2 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
            b[i + 1].balance = b[i].balance;
            b[i + 1].name = b[i].name;//Error 3 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
            b[i].balance = temp.balance;
            b[i].name = temp.name;//Error 4 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
            max.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            max.name = b[i + 1].name;//Error 5  error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
        }

    }
    max.display();
}
```

In this program I've to take input as name and balance of 10 people and display the output as name and balance corresponding to the highest balance.
Besides the errors shown in the code itself as comments, I'm also getting another code at same those lines only where I've put a comment regarding the error. That other error is:

```
IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 and the code is in visual C++

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: .. instead of `char[20]`.

Comment: And while you're at it, use `std::vector<bank> b(10)` instead of `bank b[10]`.

Comment: Look at [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) while you're at it.

Comment: Isn't there also an error in the way you access the `bank b[10]` value in the `for` loop? If you're looping from 0 to 10, and ask for `b[i+1]` when `i` is 9.. you're going out of bounds, no?

Comment: Generally in C++, one would not repeat the `public:` for each declaration, but have it generally once (since everything that follows is then public until the next `private:` or `protected:`)

Comment: I put #include<string> on the top and replaced char[20] with std::string and it worked.   Thanks

Comment: @AlejandroLucena yea, thanks, I changed it from i=0 to i<9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign `char[]` variable to another `char[]` variable. You should use `strcpy` function to do that (and dont forget to `include<cstring>` first). See this 
[how to copy char array to another char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645583/how-to-copy-char-array-to-another-char-array-in-c) for further explanation.

if it changes like this, It should be ok:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class bank
{
    public: char name[20];
    public: float balance;
    public: void get()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter name and balance in Account respectively\n";
        cin >> name >> balance;
    }
    public: void display()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << "    Balance: " << balance;
    }
};
void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    bank b[10];
    bank max;
    bank temp;
    char tempstr[20]; // use this for temporary string
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        b[i].get();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) // you should change the upper bound to 9
                            // so it not crash when i = 9
    {
        if (b[i + 1].balance > b[i].balance)
        {
            max.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            strcpy(max.name, b[i+1].name); // use strcpy
        }
        else
        {
            temp.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            strcpy(temp.name, b[i+1].name); // use strcpy
            b[i + 1].balance = b[i].balance;
            strcpy(b[i+1].name, b[i].name); // use strcpy
            b[i].balance = temp.balance;
            strcpy(b[i].name, temp.name); // use strcpy
            max.balance = b[i + 1].balance;
            strcpy(max.name, b[i+1].name); // use strcpy
        }

    }
    max.display();
}
```