# Define and use a char string in the struct

Tags: c, struct

I want to build a `struct` and contains int and char variables. Here is my code:

```
typedef struct {
        uint16_t type;      
        uint16_t sn;
        int data1;
        int data2;
        char crc[1024];
    }packet_t;
```

Then I use a method to create a `struct`:

```
packet_t packetCreate(uint16_t type,uint16_t sn, uint16_t data1, 
uint16_t data2, char crc[1024])
{
    packet_t packet;
    packet.type = type;
    packet.sn = sn; 
    packet.data1 = data1;
    packet.data2 = data2;
    packet.crc = crcr;
    return packet;
}
```

Also I have defined the corresponding variables in the code. But when I compile the  code it doesn't work and displays:

incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1024]’ from type ‘char *’ in the line: packet.crc = crcr;
How should I define and use the struct? I want to build the struct contains a char string, so I can store the CRC strings of data.

Comment: should the line be `packet.crc = crc;` instead of `packet.crc = crcr;`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16645642/817132
Or K&R's C, page 97: http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_. Only _functions_.

Answer (score 3):

Use [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy). i.e.

```
memcpy(packet.crc, crc, sizeof(packet.crc));
```

To copy the contents into the array.

You need

```
#include <string.h>
```

to use this function

Comment: NB missing comma - should be `memcpy(packet.crc, crc, sizeof(packet.crc));` - I can't try to edit this in because I need to put at least 6 characters in for that

Answer (score 3):

You cant just assign string to another string.Like

```
packet.crc = crc;
```

The above method is wrong.
You need to use command **strcpy** here from library **string**.

```
strcpy(packet.crc,crc);
```

Don't forget to call library **string.h**.

Comment: Note: C does not have a string type. It is all convention. And they are not the same types anyway. The member is an array, the paramter is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly assign arrays to each other. You may use library functions like `memcpy()`, (or `strcpy()` in the case of a null terminated string). Another way is to copy the elements from the source array to the destination one by one by a loop.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other comments I am concerned that you define your `packet_t` variable `packet` inside the function and when the function returns the memory allocated to `packet` will 'disappear'.

It is better to declare `packet` in `main` and then call the routine with the address of `packet` - or the pointer to `packet`.

You can then change your function to

```
void packetCreate(packet_t *p_packet, ruint16_t type,uint16_t sn, uint16_t data1, 
uint16_t data2, char crc[1024])
{
   // p_packetn =  &packet - it is a pointer to the packet
    p_packet->type = type;
    p_packet->sn = sn; 
    p_packet->data1 = data1;
    p_packet->data2 = data2;
    p_packet->crc = crcr; // note other answers to correct this line
    return ;
}
```