# Is pointer to struct a pointer to its first member?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, alignment

I'm learning how to work with `struct`s in C and wrote the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s1{
    unsigned short member;
};

int main()
{
    struct s1 *s1_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*s1_ptr));
    s1_ptr -> member = 10;
    printf("Member = %d\n", *s1_ptr); // Member = 10
}
```

***QUESTION:*** Is it guaranteed that in all cases a pointer to a struct is a exactly the same pointer to its first element?

In this particular case it works as I expected, but I'm not sure if it is guaranteed. Is compiler free to insert some padding in the very beginning?

The only I could find about the structure type layout is the `Section 6.2.5 Types` of [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of
>   member objects (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array),
>   each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct
>   type.

But there is nothing about padding here.

Comment: Yes and No.  The types of the pointers are different, so No (they aren't exactly the same).  The addresses the pointers point at are the same, so Yes.  See C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶15](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15): _A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning._

Comment: As noting your profile icon: Be aware that this is not (necessarily) alike in C++...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The padding at the start is covered by [6.7.2.1p15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) (emphasis mine)

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning**.

So the address of a struct is the address of of its first member. And following a pointer conversion, you are able to obtain one from the other.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not *exactly* perhaps, but at least castable.

[A pointer to a struct can be cast to a pointer to its first member (or, if the member is a bit field, to its allocation unit). Likewise, a pointer to the first member of a struct can be cast to a pointer to the enclosing struct. There may be unnamed padding between any two members of a struct or after the last member, but not before the first member.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)

So you should be able to do it.