# Struct inheritance in C. Accessing members in parent struct after type casting

Tags: c, inheritance

In the code, `child` is casted to type `Parent`, and passed to `parentMove`. `child` does not have members `x` and `y`. How does `parentMove` access `child.parent.x` and `child.parent.y`? How does type casting work here? Thx

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int x, y;
    int (*move)();
}Parent;

typedef struct {
    Parent parent;
    int h, w;
}Child;

int parentMove(Parent* parent, int y, int x){
    parent->y+=y;
    parent->x+=x;
    printf("%d %d", parent->y, parent->x);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    Parent parent = {.x = 2, .y = 1, .move = &parentMove};
    Child child = {.parent = parent, .h = 3, .w = 4};
    ((Parent*)(&child))->move((Parent*)&child, 10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Is pointer to struct a pointer to its first member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578631/is-pointer-to-struct-a-pointer-to-its-first-member). `&child == &child.parent` and the latter is a `Parent *` which is why the cast works.

Comment: `int (*move)();` should be `int (*move)(Parent* parent, int y, int x);`, is it omitted intentionally?

Comment: @csavvy I know it works so I just omitted it intentionally. Well it's a bad habit though

Comment: @Austin AFIK that's UB. So it does not work. It just behaves like it does.

Answer (score 1):

> How does parentMove access child.parent.x and child.parent.y?

It doesn't know about the child part. It doesn't matter if a Parent object is declared as a stand-alone object or as a member of Child, same thing applies in either case.

> How does type casting work here?

Poorly... you have implemented inheritance incorrectly if you have to cast to the base class from the caller side. It would seem that `Child` should have implemented its own `move` that takes a `Child*` as parameter, if only to make it a wrapper to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

**How does type casting work here?How does parentMove access child.parent.x and child.parent.y?**

In child structure, the first member is the parent structure, so internally memory representation of child structure is --

```
{
    {
        int x;         [ .. 4bytes .. ]
        int y;         [ .. 4bytes .. ]
        int *move();   [ .. 4bytes .. ]
    }
    int h;             [ .. 4bytes .. ]
    int w;             [ .. 4bytes .. ]
}
```

When you access parent.x , It is nothing but accessing first 4 bytes from starting address (i.e. &parent ). Similarly accessing parent.y means accessing 4 bytes after 4 bytes offset from starting address.

So when you pass address of child structure as a pointer to parent structure, the child-address actually points to a valid parent structure member inside, in the sense accessing first 4 bytes from the child-address is actually parent.x  similarly other members of the contained parent structure are properly be accessed.