How to write a performant & UB-free vec3::operator[] in C++?
Disclaimer: this question is more like a language lawyer question, or an attempt to find the ability boundary of compilers, so please do not overly focus on the necessity of the following requirements.
Assume I want to write a custom vec3 class that stores three floats as an array (or vector in a mathematical sense) in C++, and I expect it to meet these specifications:

Its individual members should be directly accessible like v.x, not though accessors like v.x(), since I want to use it interchangeably with, to say, glm::vec3.

It should have an operator[] that returns the corresponding element on that dimension, and the return value should be of reference type float&, since I want to use it in a generic context that accepts any "array-like", dynamically indexable type.

Its operator[] implementation should be as performant as possible, as it might be called a hell lot of times every millisecond.

It should be trivially copyable, and x, y, and z should have consecutive addresses, as I want to directly copy an array of vec3s into GPU memory and use them in a shader or something.

Its operator[] implementation should incur no UB.


I tried several implementations that I could think of (https://godbolt.org/z/5fYWb8ET8), but none of these meets all of the specifications above: the most performant ones directly violate some C++ language requirements, and the rests are not as performant. The ideal generated code should be directly calculating the returned address using base offset addressing (lea on x64) with this as base and 4*i as offset, just like the case in idx0 and idx1, but their implementation stepped into the unfortunate realm of UBs:
Implementation:
struct vec3 {
    union {
        struct {
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
        };
        float xyz[3];
    };

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx0(size_t i) {
        // UB as violating the strict aliasing rule
        return reinterpret_cast<float*>(this)[i];
    }

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx1(size_t i) {
        // The xyz variant is only used here
        // UB as accessing union from potentially non-active member
        return xyz[i];
    }
};

Generated asm on Clang:
vec3::idx0(unsigned long):
        lea     rax, [rdi + 4*rsi]
        ret

vec3::idx1(unsigned long):
        lea     rax, [rdi + 4*rsi]
        ret

Other implementations, including manually dispatching using if, switch, indexing on absolute addresses, and indexing on relative addresses, all resulted in far less efficient assembly codes:
struct vec3 {
    // same data members as above

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx2(size_t i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return x;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            return y;
        } else if (i == 2) {
            return z;
        } else {
            std::unreachable();
        }
    }

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx3(size_t i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return x;
            case 1:
                return y;
            case 2:
                return z;
            default:
                std::unreachable();
        }
    }

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx4(size_t i) {
        auto addrs = std::array{&x, &y, &z};
        return *addrs[i];
    }

    [[gnu::used]] constexpr float& idx5(size_t i) {
        auto accessors = std::array{&vec3::x, &vec3::y, &vec3::z};
        return this->*accessors[i];
    }
};

Generated asm on Clang:
vec3::idx2(unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB2_4
        cmp     rsi, 2
        jne     .LBB2_2
        add     rax, 8
.LBB2_4:
        ret
.LBB2_2:
        add     rax, 4
        ret

vec3::idx3(unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB3_4
        cmp     rsi, 2
        jne     .LBB3_2
        add     rax, 8
.LBB3_4:
        ret
.LBB3_2:
        add     rax, 4
        ret

vec3::idx4(unsigned long):
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 24], rdi
        lea     rax, [rdi + 4]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 16], rax
        add     rdi, 8
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8*rsi - 24]
        ret

vec3::idx5(unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rip + .L__const.vec3::idx5(unsigned long).accessors]
        add     rax, qword ptr [rcx + 8*rsi]
        ret

.L__const.vec3::idx5(unsigned long).accessors:
        .quad   0
        .quad   4
        .quad   8

I also tried to provide the compiler with extra information (using [[assume]] or built-ins alike) that might help it analyze out the numeric relationship between i and the returned address, but neither of them worked.

Is there any way to instruct the compilers to generate the ideal code, with implementation written in "standard", UB-free C++? I might have just not found the correct way to tell the compilers about the extra information.
If not, is it because of the restriction of language standards, or is it because of the lack of certain optimization techniques in compilers? In idx5's case, the compilers might have been able to figure out that the loaded offset always has the same value as 4*i.

Also, is there any certain change (or any existing proposal) in the C++ standard that might help this situation? The closest things I can think of are as follows; would they solve the problem?
1. Allowing access to non-active members of a union, whose members are all of trivially copyable non-padded types.

2. Wait for the implementation of `std::start_lifetime_as`, and use it to implement the `operator[]` as `idx6`.


what are your indicators for "ideal code" ? Benchmarks? Number of instructions?

Simply use -fnostrict-aliasing... that's what the kernel people do afaik, who are extremely interested in performance.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I judge this in this case by the number of instructions.

If you don't need the triples consecutively in memory in the case of vec3[]s (which you'd need e.g. for simd), and if you are not memory constrained, you could hold an additional const reference x, y and z to each array element (and no union at all).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, you're right, but -fno-strict-aliasing is kinda "non-standard-conformant", and as I stated, this is a language-lawyer-esque question. I'm just curious about whether it could be implemented with only C++ codes.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica You remind me of this. I'll add it as an extra requirement.

@KirisameIgna Would using a vec3 view be an option? I'm not sure how well that works with glm::vec3 but it should be extremely easy for the compiler to optimize.

Are you going to iterate over the elements when treated as an array? I.e., will the index be variable at the call sites or will it always (mostly) be a constant? If the latter, the manual dispatch version should be preferred. Its assembly when not inlined is irrelevant. And it still gives you well-defined behavior with the best performance when inlined (assuming that the compiler can eliminate the branches that are not taken).

taking the address of x instead of this should at least avoid the strict aliasing rule violation, but adding any offset to it is still UB, because the resulting pointer is not pointing in the same container ... there is no container, and (&x + 1) == &y is not guaranteed.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904491/in-c-is-it-valid-to-treat-scalar-members-of-a-struct-as-if-they-comprised-an

Just to clarify, even though you say "no UB", you are stilll willing for v[3] to cause UB?

I presume you're not happy with making v.x work via  float arr[3]; public: float& get_x() { return arr[0]; } and #define x get_x().

Here's where we might wish that nested classes could access members of the enclosing class.  You could then have something along the lines of class vec { float arr[3]; public: class x_accessor { operator float& () { return arr[0]; } } x; }


If not, is it because of the restriction of language standards, or is it bacause of the lack of certain optimization techniques in compilers?

To answer this part of the question: The reason is that you have three members at addresses this + 0, this + 4 and this + 8 -- but this + 0 is just this. This breaks the symmetry and the compiler no longer recognizes the pattern.
You can see this in action by adding a dummy member to the start of the class, which makes clang optimize this correctly.
I filed an issue for this here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/118548

You can make idx0 have defined behavior with
return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(this) + sizeof(float)*i));

and then you can dismiss the union and only need the individual-member implementation.
This still assumes that there won't be any padding between the members, which is not guaranteed by the standard. However, you can verify it with offsetof in a static_assert.
What this solution won't permit is to take the address of the return value again to perform pointer arithmetic on it. The caller will get access only to the single float member.
This also doesn't work at compile-time. If that is required you need to add a if consteval branch that calls idx2 or one of the other implementations instead.
Also, I assume that the defects discussed in P1839 are resolved in a reasonable form (e.g. as suggested in that paper). Otherwise technically the above is at the moment still UB, because reinterpret_cast<std::byte*> (and reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>) is, against the assumptions made by everyone, currently not specified to do the expected thing, i.e. to produce a pointer into the object's object representation on which pointer arithmetic can be performed.

Also, on a side note, the original idx0 didn't really violate the aliasing rule, but instead the preconditions of the built-in + operator.
