# Passing a element of a char array into another position

Tags: c, string, char

So i have a struct with the following elements:

```
typedef struct loja{
    int numero;
    char nome[MAX];
    float area;
    float faturacao[12];
} Loja[N];
```

i declared an array vetC[ ] for the struct and my next step was to eliminate a posicion of that array

```
int EliminarComum(int c,Loja vetC[]){    
    int posicao, i,a;  

    posicao = MostrarComum(c,vetC);  ///only for the user to choose the position he wishes to eliminate.
    if (posicao > c)  
        printf("can't delete.\n");  

    else {  
        for (i = posicao - 1; i < c - 1; i++){  
            vetC[i]->numero = vetC[i+1]->numero;  
            vetC[i]->nome = vetC[i+1]->nome;  
            vetC[i]->area = vetC[i+1]->area;  
            for(a=0;a<12;a++)  
                vetC[i]->faturacao[a] = vetC[i+1]->faturacao[a];  
            c--;  
        }  
    }  
    return c;  
}
```

and in the line of `vetC[i]->nome = vetC[i+1]->nome;` gives me the error

> **error**: assignment to expression with array type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645583/how-to-copy-a-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays, but you could assign complete `struct loja`-objects:

```
vetC[i] = vetC[i+1];
```

Conver, for example, the following simple program, which illustrates how an assignment of struct-objects works, while an assignment of a char-array fails:

```
struct testStruct {

    int x;
    char str[10];
};

int main() {

    struct testStruct t1 = { 10, "Hello" };
    struct testStruct t2;

    t2 = t1;  // legal.

    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    char str2[10];

    // str2 = str1;  // illegal; arrays cannot be assigned.

    strcpy(str2,str1);  // legal (as long as str1 is a valid string)
}
```

Comment: tytyty <3 love you i was able to do it :D