# why won't %s print from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, c-strings, strcpy

I created a linked list that contains a char array. Then I tried to print it using %s and it would not print. I know I have to transform the char by adding in '\0' so that it can print using '/0'. But I'm not sure why.

For example if I input:

> Bob 20

It should print:

> New student created: Bob is 20 years old.

BUT: it's printing (without "Bob"):

> New student created:  is 20 years old.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
      char name[50];
      int age;
      struct student *next;
};


struct student *createStudent(char studentName[], int studentAge);

int main(void) {
    struct student *studptr;
    int myAge;
    char myName[50];
    scanf("%s %d", myName, &myAge);
    studptr = createStudent(myName, myAge);
    printf("New student created: %s is %d years old.\n", studptr->name, studptr->age);
    free(studptr);
    return 0;
}

struct student *createStudent(char studentName[], int studentAge){

    struct student * ptr;
    ptr = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    ptr->name[50] = studentName[50];
    ptr->age = studentAge;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

NOTE: I understand the code below will work and print the correct name, where I add an additional method to change the char array called copyStr(), but I'm not sure why....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
      char name[50];
      int age;
      struct student *next;
};


struct student *createStudent(char studentName[], int studentAge);
void copyStr(char *source, char *target);

int main(void) {
    struct student *studptr;
    int myAge;
    char myName[50];
    scanf("%s %d", myName, &myAge);
    studptr = createStudent(myName, myAge);
    printf("New student created: %s is %d years old.\n", studptr->name, studptr->age);
    free(studptr);
    return 0;
}

struct student *createStudent(char studentName[], int studentAge){

    struct student * ptr;
    ptr = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    //we need to translate the char into a string
    copyStr(studentName, ptr->name);


    ptr->name[50] = studentName[50];
    ptr->age = studentAge;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}

void copyStr(char *source, char *target){

    int i = 0;
    while(source[i] != '\0')
    {
        target[i] = source[i];
        i++;
    }
    target[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `ptr->name[50] = studentName[50];` that's not how you copy arrays in C; that copies a single character. And worse, that invokes *undefined behavior* by access the arrays outside of their declared size. (both are `char[50]` and therefore only indexable from 0..49 inclusively).

Comment: You are copying character and that too beyond the limits `ptr->name[50] = studentName[50]` **+** Use `strcpy` instead of some copy function

Comment: See [How to copy a char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645583/how-to-copy-a-char-array-in-c) for an explanation of why copying strings requires a loop.

Comment: The `copyStr` function is unnecessary. The standard library already has `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

This statement

```
ptr->name[50] = studentName[50];
```

tries to assign the non-existent element with the index 50 of the array pointed to by the pointer studentName to the non-existent element of the array ptr->name.

Instead you should use the standard C function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

For example

```
strcpy( ptr->name, studentName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Vlad's answer, Right way to copy arrays is by iterating over them, thereby, picking each element in char array and copying it to new location. `strncpy` does exactly that along with  buffer overflow checks, which makes it better than `strcpy`.

Please have a look at [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) documentation, which says :  "ensure size of the array pointed by destination shall be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with source"

On a completely different side note, if you're looking for one-liner assignment, you're allowed to do this:

```
   char sample[] = {"randomText"};
   char sample2[11] = {"randomText"};
```