# How to solve is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd

Tags: c, valgrind

valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes -v ./out

```
==37408== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 23 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==37408== 
==37408== 1 errors in context 1 of 23:
==37408== Invalid read of size 1
==37408==    at 0x707E: memmove$VARIANT$sse42 (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37408==    by 0x10F08F: strdup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==37408==    by 0x10000576A: new_node (parser.c:349)
==37408==    by 0x100005E5D: string_literal (parser.c:166)
==37408==    by 0x100001A5D: yyparse (vtl4.y:142)
==37408==    by 0x1000029F1: main (vtl4.y:218)
==37408==  Address 0x100055826 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==37408==    at 0x58D3: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37408==    by 0x100006734: strclip (util.c:35)
==37408==    by 0x100005E4B: string_literal (parser.c:164)
==37408==    by 0x100001A5D: yyparse (vtl4.y:142)
==37408==    by 0x1000029F1: main (vtl4.y:218)
==37408== 
==37408== 
==37408== 1 errors in context 2 of 23:
==37408== Invalid read of size 1
==37408==    at 0x67A4: strlen (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37408==    by 0x10F066: strdup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==37408==    by 0x10000576A: new_node (parser.c:349)
==37408==    by 0x100005E5D: string_literal (parser.c:166)
==37408==    by 0x100001A5D: yyparse (vtl4.y:142)
==37408==    by 0x1000029F1: main (vtl4.y:218)
==37408==  Address 0x100055826 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==37408==    at 0x58D3: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37408==    by 0x100006734: strclip (util.c:35)
==37408==    by 0x100005E4B: string_literal (parser.c:164)
==37408==    by 0x100001A5D: yyparse (vtl4.y:142)
==37408==    by 0x1000029F1: main (vtl4.y:218)
==37408== 
==37408== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 23 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

new_node (parser.c:349)：

```
struct simpleNode *new_node(JJT jjt,char *node_image){
    struct simpleNode *a = malloc(sizeof(struct simpleNode));
    if (a==NULL) {
        yyerror("FUNC[%s]error:Init a new simple error,out of space!",__func__);
        exit(0);
    }
    a->info.astn = jjt;
    a->info.node_name = jjtNodeName[jjt];

    **349**>>a->info.image = strdup(node_image);
    a->info.already_rendered = cJSON_False;
    a->parent = NULL;
    a->firstChild = NULL;
    a->nextSibling = NULL;
    return a;
}
```

string_literal (parser.c:166):

```
struct simpleNode* string_literal( char *str){
    //printf("%s node!\n",__func__);
    char *strc = strclip(str, strlen(str) - 2, 1);
    //printf("**********strclip:%s\n",strc);
   **166**>> struct simpleNode* a = new_node(JJTSTRINGLITERAL,strc);
    //free(strc);
    free(str);
    str = NULL;
    return a;
}
```

strclip (util.c:35)

```
char * strclip(const char *src, unsigned long n, unsigned long m) {

    unsigned long len = strlen(src);
    if (n > len)
        n = len - m;
    if (m > len)
        return NULL ;
    const char * right_start = src + m;

   **35**<< char *q = (char *) calloc(n, sizeof(char));

    strncpy(q, right_start, n);

    return q;
}
```

I study for a long time didn't find the root cause of the problem, please help me！

Answer (score 6):

[`strncpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) in `strclip()` is the cause of your problem;

> *No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num*. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

Since you're using `calloc()` anyway to get memory filled with zeroes, all you need to do is allocate an extra char that won't be overwritten;

```c
char *q = (char *) calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(q, right_start, n);
```

This will leave the last char of the buffer as zero, so you have a guaranteed termination of the string.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` at all, [strncpy is not a secure version of strcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure). The proper, fastest-possible way to do this is malloc, memcpy and then a manual null termination.