# C Array to Char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need some guidence on pointers and array's

```
char *ptr;
char Array1[20];

ptr = malloc(sizeof(Array1));
```

now how can i get the entire Array1 into the ptr??

I have tried strcat, strncat, strcpy. Also i tried a loop then using the mentioned functions and adding each element of th array and nothing

```
int a = 0
while ( a <= sizeof(Array1) )
{
     strcpy(ptr, Array1[a]);
     a++; 
}
```

I really need to know how to get the array into a pointer.

Comment: Your `a <= sizeof(Array)` would be out of bounds regardless since the index of `Array1` goes from `0` to `sizeof(Array1)-1`.

Comment: I fixed what I think is a typo; changed `pts` to `ptr`.

Comment: `str...` functions are for strings, which are null terminated sequences of non-null characters.

Comment: Sure for pts? Not ptr?

Answer (score 9):

Use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(Array1));
if (ptr)
{
    memcpy(ptr, Array1, sizeof(Array1));
}
```

The `str*` family of functions are dependent upon the presence of null terminator characters.

If `Array1` does contain a string, terminated by a null character, then [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) would operate correctly.
[`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) requires the presence of a null terminator in the destination buffer as well as the source buffer to function correctly.

If `Array1` does not contain a null terminated string then do not use the `str*` functions, use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: +1 but extra brownie points if you point out why you can't use strcpy and strncpy.

Comment: `strncpy` could be used, and may even be better than `memcpy` if `Array1` is supposed to contain a string

Comment: @MattMcNabb `strncpy` has no advantages over `memcpy`. If `Array1` is correctly nul terninated, everything OK. But if not, `strncpy` wont fix it.

Comment: `strncpy` has the advantage that it does not read junk in the source array that comes after the null terminator (if there was one). Heartbeat? :)

Comment: There are two cases where you use strncpy: 1) you are some hardened UNIX veteran programming 40 years old computers, or 2) you are confused. [strncpy() was never a safer version of strcpy()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure), that's just an urban legend created by confused people, so that they sound smart when they speak to even more confused people. On the contrary, strncpy() is a dangerous function. [More info about why strncpy is dangerous and unsafe](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/).

Answer (score 1):

> now how can i get the entire Array1 into the ptr??

Use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(ptr, Array1, sizeof(Array1));
```

> Also I tried a loop then using the mentioned functions and adding each element of th array

That loop is incorrect, because you are treating an array of `char`s as an array of `char*`.

> I really need to know how to get the array into a pointer.

The name of the array converts freely to a pointer to the initial array element. That is why you can pass `Array1` to `memcpy`, which takes a pointer. In general, `Array1` expression is the same as `&Array1[0]`, which is the explicit way of taking the address of the initial array element.

Answer (score 0):

For added hilarity, you can do it entirely without getting your hands or the standard library's hands dirty with pesky loops and let the compiler do the hard work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  char a[20] = "Hello World today!!";
  char* const p = malloc(sizeof a); 
  union {
    char* volatile p;
    struct {
      char a[20];
    }* s;
  } destination = {.p = p}, source = {.p = a}; 
  *destination.s = *source.s;
  printf("%s\n",p);
  return 0;
}
// tested with CFLAGS:='-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11'
```

Although **it should be mentionend** that this is not technically compliant with the C standard specification, because we're hiding a cast by using a union and the standard doesn't allow us to use unions in this way (you have to promise to only use the union member that you last wrote to, which we break when using the `s` member).

But it's more fun than using the library or those loop things, don't you agree? :)
(*Disclaimer: This is using loops, too (or rather implicitly unrolled loops). We just don't see them.*)

---

**Edit** I was just curious and had a look at what clang (3.2, rather dated, granted) generates from this and it seems to actually translate this into a memcpy call (last line).

```
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca [20 x i8], align 16
  %p = alloca i8*, align 8
  %destination = alloca %union.anon, align 8
  %source = alloca %union.anon, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  %2 = bitcast [20 x i8]* %a to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %2, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x i8]* @main.a, i32 0, i32 0), i64 20, i32 16, i1 false)
  %3 = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 20) nounwind
  store i8* %3, i8** %p, align 8
  %4 = bitcast %union.anon* %destination to i8**
  %5 = load i8** %p, align 8
  store volatile i8* %5, i8** %4, align 8
  %6 = bitcast %union.anon* %source to i8**
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds [20 x i8]* %a, i32 0, i32 0
  store volatile i8* %7, i8** %6, align 8
  %8 = bitcast %union.anon* %destination to %struct.anon**
  %9 = load %struct.anon** %8, align 8
  %10 = bitcast %union.anon* %source to %struct.anon**
  %11 = load %struct.anon** %10, align 8
  %12 = bitcast %struct.anon* %9 to i8*
  %13 = bitcast %struct.anon* %11 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %12, i8* %13, i64 20, i32 1, i1 false)
```