# What is the 'l' for in strlcpy?

Tags: c, bsd, c-strings

What does the 'l' in `strlcpy` stand for? I'm certain after asking it will be horribly obvious but I can't seem to dredge up a solid answer anywhere.

Comment: You mean you can't find the answer in the [man pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3)?

Comment: From [an answer to another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115015/434551): "strlcpy is indeed a true limited-length copying function created for working with C-strings.". It seems the `l` in `strlcpy` stands for `limited-length`.

Comment: So it's purely to denote 'length'? I guess as a converse to 'number' / 'n' (`strncpy`) and the confusion surrounding that?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, as I said (and had that open while asking) I was unfortunately certain it would be horribly obvious after asking. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm running ubuntu/linux version 14.04 and strlcpy is not even listed in the man/info pages.  Where are the rest of you finding that function?

Comment: @user3629249: it is a (classic) BSD extension. (and it makes sense, since the caller already knows the 1st argument , which is returned by the standard `strcpy()` )

Comment: I don't have any BSD distro either, but if you follow the link @JeffMercado gave above you can see the contents of the subsequent man page.

Comment: Just about any C programmer came up with their own "fixed version" of strcpy().  First time I saw it I went "this is completely borken" and wrote strfcpy().  f as in "fixed".  So, erm, l as in "limited".

Comment: Am I the only one around here who thinks `strcpy` isn't broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strlcpy` was introduced at USENIX 1999 by Todd C. Miller and Theo de Raadt (OpenBSD project).

From the Proceedings paper, [strlcpy and strlcat — Consistent, Safe, String Copy and Concatenation](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix99/full_papers/millert/millert.pdf), in the abstract it is written:

> The proposed replacement functions, strlcpy() and strlcat(),
>   address these problems by presenting an API designed for safe string copies (see Figure 1 for function prototypes).
>   Both functions guarantee NUL-termination, take as a length parameter the size of the string in bytes, and
>   provide an easy way to detect truncation

It is therefore pretty obvious the `l` stands for *length*.

Comment: It was a time in history when the reference section in security papers always had [1]  Aleph One paper on buffer overflows and [2] Bugtraq mailing listing link.