# array assigning in C

Tags: c, arrays, character-arrays

I have some device i need to connect with by ASCII Commands.
i declared some chars array and each command state i assigning it with the request command and then sent it through UART.

Do i have another option to assign the array instead of do it as follows?(for example)

```
    Buf[0]='M'; 
    Buf[1]='O';
    Buf[2]='D';
    Buf[3]='E';
    Buf[4]='L';
    Buf[5]=' ';
   .
   .
   .
```

what i thought is to declare char array for each command and each state i will copy the requested command array to the one will be sent to the UART.

Comment: `char Buf[]="MODEL ";` or `char Buf[SIZE]; strcpy(Buf,"MODEL ");`

Comment: `strncpy(Buf, "MODEL ", 6` or `sprintf(Buf, "MODEL ")`

Comment: @kyriosli Please never use strncpy. It is a very dangerous function since nobody manages to use it correctly. It is **only good for creating bugs**, as in your case. Run this code and you'll see what I mean: `char buf[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'b', 'u', 'g'}; strncpy(buf, "MODEL ", 6); puts(buf);` In particular, [strncpy was never intended to be a safer version of strcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify whether the buffer is `'\0'`-terminated so it is impossible to give one particular answer.

There are several options:

```
char Buf[]="MODEL ";
```

This makes it `'\0'`-terminated. If you don't want `'\0'`-termination, you can do:

```
char Buf[] = {'M','O','D','E','L',' '};
```

If you want to leave the array uninitialized and populate it later, you could do:

```
char Buf[SIZE];
strcpy(Buf,"MODEL ");
```

...but if you do that, please do ensure that `SIZE` is large enough, otherwise you run into problems.

It's also possible to do:

```
char Buf[SIZE];
memcpy(Buf,"MODEL ", 6); // or memcpy(Buf, "MODEL ", sizeof("MODEL ")-1);
```

if you don't want `'\0'` termination. If you do that, please also ensure that `SIZE` is large enough. If you use the variant in the comment, please consider also using `#define THE_STRING "MODEL "` and then using `THE_STRING` instead of `"MODEL "` to avoid repeating the string literal twice.

Comment: Just a tip: instead of using strlen to know the size of a string literal in runtime, you could do `memcpy(Buf, "MODEL ", sizeof("MODEL ")); // includes null term` or better yet, `#define THE_STRING "MODEL "  ... memcpy(Buf, THE_STRING, sizeof(THE_STRING));`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that strlen() isn't the most optimal way, so I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can typedef string to realize what you are doing and it becomes something like java and C#

```
typedef char* string;
/* The entry point */
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
string str;
str = "Hello, World";
puts(str);// or fputs(str,strlen(str),stdout);
return 0;
}
```

This does not have any difference with what juhist just said.