# Index into a char array to append a string

Tags: c, string

I am doing this to append some text:

```
char text[100];
strcpy(text, "Hello");

char input[] = "random";
strncpy(text + strlen(text), input, sizeof(text) - strlen(text));
```

I did this and it seems to work fine for ASCII text. But I fear I am not being safe doing pointer arithmetic. What if the input is UTF-8?

FYI, when I do `text + strlen(text)` I am getting a pointer to the end of the sentence and then appending to the end of the sentence.

i.e.

`text => |h|e|l|l|o|NUL||||||....`

`text + strlen(text) => |NUL|||||.....`

Comment: Why not use `strcat` ?

Comment: what's your concern about utf-8?

Comment: Actually I was confused. I'm concerned of situations where ``text+1`` is not equal to text[1].

Comment: In general, you should avoid `strncpy`, it is a [dangerous and unsafe function only ever intended to be used for anything but ancient string formats in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure). Better and safer alternatives are `memcpy` and `strcpy` (with buffer size known/checked).

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why strcat exists:

```
char text[100];
strcpy(text, "Hello");

char input[] = "random";
strcat(text, input);
```

To ensure memory sensitive concatenation preventing overflow, please use the following amendment:

```
   char *text;

   //allocate memory
   text = (char *) malloc(15);
   strcpy(text, "Hello");


   char input[] = "random";

   //reallocate memory
   text = (char *) realloc(text, strlen(text)+strlen(input) +1);
   strcat(text, input);
   free(text);
```

Comment: What if the ``text`` buffer isn't large enough. And if I use ``strncat`` I still need to calculate how much empty space is left over in ``text`` right?

Comment: Please add a note to your solution that a caller function is then responsible for freeing the memory allocated by `concat` after use.

Comment: Yes, `strcat` simplifies the task – but it does no size testing and can overflow the destination array, as opposite to the OP's approach.