# What is string overlapping according to the C Standard?

Tags: c, standards, c-strings, strncpy, c-standard-library

From the C Standard:

> 7.21.2.4 The strncpy function
>
> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

---

What is overlapping?

It is clear that it is overlapping when the beginning of the destination string crosses the ending of the source string.

But is overlapping taking place in the next example?

```
const char* dateConst = "2017-01-25";
char* date = malloc(16);
strcpy(date, dateConst);

strncpy(date+4, date+5, 2);
strncpy(date+6, date+8, 3);

printf("%s\n", date);
```

Output: 20170125

If strncpy just copyes symbols char by char like it is in [this implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/ppc.subproj/strncpy.c), there should be no problem.

Comment: While it is the C standard the dictates the behavior of `strncpy`, you seem to be compiling C++..

Comment: `strncpy` is a dangerous function and should be avoided. It was never intended to be used with null terminated strings to begin with. Instead, use `memcpy` or `strcpy`.

Comment: @Lundin Wow, I've never heard that  before. Why would you recommend `strcpy` over `strncpy`? (I've always heard the other way around.)

Comment: @LeifAndersen Because `strncpy` has a tendency to leave out the null terminator. It was never intended to be used for null-terminated strings in the first place, nor was it ever intended to be a "safe strcpy". [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115015/584518). As for `strcpy` being unsafe that's partially true, partially a myth created by Microsoft. As long as you know the size of the data to copy, it is perfectly safe. If you just copy an unknown string from an input buffer, with no error checking, well then obviously things will go wrong - no fault of strcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If strncpy just copyes symbols char by char like it is in this
>   implementation, there should be no problem.

This is exactly the problem.
The standard doesn't specify which way the function must operate, but what output should give, and, in the same time, specify that if there is any kind of overlap the result is **UB** making coders free to use whatever approach they like .

This is because new instructions or processor architectures could sponsor the use of new and more efficient instructions that could follow a different addressing way (i.e. copy in reverse order or in mixed order). This could give you whichever result not predictable, in fact an **undefined behavior**.

Eventually you can use `memmove` function that explicitly allows overlapping, or write your own function that is overlap aware.

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy` doesn't have to be implemented in any specific way. The C standard only dictates the API contract it should follow. Any *specific* implementation may choose to make overlap a non-issue, but it isn't forced to do so by the standard.

`strncpy` can be implemented in terms of `memcpy`, which is subject to undefined behavior when the source and destination overlap. But with the specification mentioned above, it's perfectly okay.

Comment: `memcpy` don't accept overlapping, `memove` allows overlapping. You may want fix the answer.

Comment: @Frankie_C - I don't since I meant what I said and said what I meant. `strncpy` can have undefined behavior in case of overlapping, so it **can** use `memcpy` (in a possible library implementation) and put the blame on the user if things overlap.

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood. If you agree I'll remove all comments.

Comment: @Frankie_C - Nah, it's okay. You prompted me to better explain that point in case it wasn't clear.