# C standard library function 'strncpy' not working

Tags: c, c-strings, standard-library

C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define STRINGS 10
#define STR_LEN 20

int main(void)
{
    char words[STRINGS][STR_LEN];

    char input[STR_LEN];

    int i;
    int mycount;

    for(i = 0;i < STRINGS;++i;)
    {
        printf("Enter a word (or 0 to quit)\n:");

        scanf("%19s", input);

        if(input[0] == '0') break;

        strncpy(words[i], input, STR_LEN);

        mycount++;
    }

    printf("A total of %d strings were entered!\n",mycount);

}
```

problem: When I run this code and enter some strings it doesn't print out the amount of strings I entered

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GiOk.png)

Comment: `for(i = 0;i < STRINGS;++i;)` doesn't compile. BTW `i` and `mycount` are the same, except for the fact that `mycount` was never initialized.

Comment: you forgot to initialize `mycount` to zero

Comment: Just a hint: Finding an obvious error in the C standard library of a major implementation would not be unheard of, but it is extremely unlikely. This stuff is 20 or 30 years old. Comparatively unlikely to finding a compiler error, or a CPU bug. I suppose most of us suspected one or the other at some point, but it was almost never true. Like, I had a colleague around 1997 who *did* find a bug in a Z80 clone. That unlikely. In all other instances the error was a more or less subtle coding error, or an error in the build environment setup.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`, it is a dangerous function and was never intended to be used for null terminated strings, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to initalize mycount to 0.

```
int mycount =0;
```

Comment: Please at least make the OP provide critical information in text, rather than images.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `mycount` is uninitialized. You then attempt to modify it in the `for` loop via the `++` operator.  So you're reading garbage values and writing garbage values.  This explains the output you're getting.

Reading an uninitialized variable invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, it manifests as garbage values, but it could just as easily output the expected value or cause a crash.

Initialize this variable at the time it is declared.

```
int mycount = 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "writing an uninitialized variable"

Comment: @Bathsheba Good catch.  Edited.