# Extra care should be taken to ensure that character arrays that are allocated on the stack are used safely

Tags: c, security, code-analysis

I performing the code analysis of my embedded C code with SonarQube and [RATS](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/codetools/rats.shtml)
 (Rough Auditing Tool for Security).

Under Ubuntu Shell, I execute

> rats --quiet --xml -w 1 . > ./rats_report.xml

to get the the report that will be imported into SonarQube.

I get some errors like this:

> Extra care should be taken to ensure that character arrays that are allocated on the stack are used safely. They are prime targets for buffer overflow attacks.

This is a snippet code of the function that generates the error:

```
static char* GetQueryStringForValue( const char* valueLabel )
{
  static char queryString[QUERY_LEN + 1];

  memcpy( queryString, '\0', sizeof(queryString) );
  snprintf( queryString, sizeof(queryString), "{'%s'", valueLabel );

  return queryString;
}
```

I understand that the problem is related to the buffer allocated into the stack.

My question is: which is the best practice to prevent buffer overflow attacks?

Should I add particular controls?

Thanks for the help!

BR,
Federico

Comment: `memcpy`? Are you thinking of `memset`? `memcpy` is expecting a pointer for the second argument, not the integer `'\0'`.

Comment: Strangely `static char queryString[QUERY_LEN + 1];` *isn't* allocated on the stack.

Comment: Before you worry about security and static analysis, make sure that the code actually compiles and gives the expected results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a false positive, nothing is allocated "on the stack" here. With the `static` storage class specifier, `queryString` has *static storage duration* which means it exists during the entire execution time of your program. No implementation of C would place such an object *on the stack*.

But this function is still very wrong:

```
memcpy( queryString, '\0', sizeof(queryString) );
```

This is attempting to dereference a `NULL` pointer (the `NUL` character constant is implicitly converted to a `NULL` pointer). What you probably meant is

```
memset(queryString, 0, sizeof queryString);
```

---

That said, if you still receive this warning, take it as what it is: a warning. It warns you to take extra care. With the code fixed to use `memset()`, there's no way to overflow your `queryString` here.

---

Your code has something different to worry about: It's not *thread safe*, due to the use of a `static` variable. It would probably be better to let the caller provide the buffer for the `queryString`.

Comment: Thanks Felix for the explanation. So the best way to initialize a string is to use the memset and the '0' values. I used the memcpy because, I though, the in this way I always have a string with the terminator and if I use the strcpy my string in safe because I have already the terminator.

Comment: @Federico the cheapest way to initialise the empty string is to write `0` to its first byte.

Comment: @Federico: `snprintf()` terminates the `char`-array for you, so just drop this `mem*()` thingy.

Comment: Yes the best practice is use the snprintf. Is more secure. just for my understanding, if I write 0 on the first string byte and I use the strcpy, I can fall into an buffer overflow error. So the best practice is initialize the first byte to zero and use snprintf

Comment: @Federico *if I write 0 on the first string byte and I use the strcpy, I can fall into an buffer overflow error. So the best practice is initialize the first byte to zero and use snprintf* First, if you're using `strcpy()` or `snprintf()` to copy a string to a buffer, there's no need to initialize it with any type of zero as `strcpy()` and `snprintf()` both completely overwrite the buffers previous contents up to the length of the buffer or the terminating `\0` character in the copied string.  Second, you can also use the C-standard function `strncpy()` to safely copy a string into a buffer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle be careful with `strncpy()`, it has some *surprising* semantics. The most problematic part is that there's no `NUL` terminator written to  the destination if it isn't among the first `n` characters of the source. This is kind of a *poisonous* function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `strncpy()` should never be used in mission-critical systems, if at all. It's a wide-spread, incorrect myth that it is some sort of safer version of `strcpy()`. See [Why are strlcpy and strlcat considered insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure).