# Why strncpy() is not respecting the given size_t n which is 10 in temp2?

Tags: c, string, strncpy

This problem is blowing my mind...Can anyone please sort out the problem because i have already wasted hours on this.. ;(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

  char string[] = "Iam pretty much big string.";
  char temp1[50];
  char temp2[10];

  // strcpy() and strncpy()
   strcpy(temp1, string);
   printf("%s\n", temp1);

  strncpy(temp2, temp1, 10);
  printf("%s\n", temp2);
  return 0;
}
```

Result

```
Iam pretty much big string.
Iam prettyIam pretty much big string.
```

Expected Result:

```
Iam pretty much big string.
Iam pretty
```

Comment: `strncpy()`, despite its name, was not designed to deal with *strings*: it does not manage the terminating '`\0`' in the usual way --- specifically it may leave the destination array with no zero byte (or over write with zeros more data than needed in the context of *strings*)

Comment: @pmg, it does deal with strings, in the sense that it stops copying and starts zero-padding if it reaches the end of the input *string*.  It's the output side of the function that deals with non-string records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strncpy` function *is* respecting the 10 byte limit you're giving it.

It copies the first 10 bytes from `string` to `temp2`.  None of those 10 bytes is a null byte, and the size of `temp2` is 10, so there are no null bytes in `temp2`.  When you then pass `temp2` to `printf`, it reads past the end of the array invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You would need to set the size given to `strncpy` to the array size - 1, then manually  add the null byte to the end.

```
strncpy(temp2, temp1, sizeof(temp2)-1);
temp2[sizeof(temp2)-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I was not aware of adding null byte at the end manually...i thought this will be added automatically..btw i added '\0' instead of only 0 because it was randring 0 as an ascii code.

Comment: @Zafeer If the source string was less than 10 bytes long it *would* add the null terminator.  However it didn't because it was 10 or more bytes long.

Comment: i understand now..that was kinda unexpected behavior for me but with the help of you guys this concept is crystal clear for me :)

Answer (score 4):

The address of `temp2` is just before the address of `temp1` and because you do not copy the final `0`, the printf will continue printing after the end of temp2.

As time as you do not insert the `0`, the result of `printf` is undefined.

Comment: nitpick #2: it's less ambiguous as `'\0'`, not `0` ;-) i also say `NUL` (with one `L` sometimes, but that will probably annoy someone

Comment: @underscore_d NUL is what ASCII calls the 0 byte, so if it annoys someone, blame the people who came up with it.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between them, I should have written NUL.  But I corrected and inserted the number zero.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that's not the literal ASCII character `'0'`, but the escaped control character `'\0'`

Comment: @underscore_d ok.

Comment: I realise my comment to David's answer was just a rehash of your answer.  I got so carried away in the fight about termination characters I failed to read the answer itself!

Answer (score 4):

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to print `temp2` as `temp2` is not *nul-terminated*. From `man strncpy`:

> "**Warning:** If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src,
>   the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated." (emphasis in
>   original)

See also [C11 Standard - 7.24.2.4 The strncpy function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.4) (specifically *footnote:* 308)

So `temp2` is not nul-terminated.

Comment: _Undefined Behaviour_ could mean literally anything happens, but in real life it's often pretty easy to see what will happen / has happened.  In this case, your `temp1` array is likely immediately after `temp2` on the stack, so - in the absence of the terminating `\0` - `printf` carries on reading characters and starts printing `temp1` as well, until it reaches _its_ termination.

Comment: Agreed, but if you talk about a specific stack order -- someone is bound to point out that it doesn't hold for all cases `:)` (A Hobson's Choice) Easiest solution here is just `temp2[9] = 0;` after the copy.

Comment: @DavidCRankin, you are technically correct; the best kind of correct!

Comment: i added a null character at the end of temp2 and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Citation of the appropriate `[strncpy]` tag on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/tags/strncpy/info, which may help you to understand what happens exactly:

---

This function is not recommended to use for any purpose, neither in C nor C++. [It was never intended to be a "safe version of `strcpy`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure) but is often misused for such purposes. It is in fact considered to be much more dangerous than `strcpy`, since the null termination mechanism of `strncpy` is not intuitive and therefore often misunderstood. This is because of the following behavior specified by ISO 9899:2011 7.24.2.4:

> ```
> char *strncpy(char * restrict s1, 
>      const char * restrict s2, 
>      size_t n);
> ```
>
> /--/
>
> 3  If the array pointed to by **s2** is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters
>   are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by **s1**, until n characters in all have been
>   written.

A very common mistake is to pass an `s2` which is exactly as many characters as the `n` parameter, in which case `s1` will not get null terminated. That is: `strncpy(dst, src, strlen(src));`

```
/* MCVE of incorrect use of strncpy */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  const char* STR = "hello";
  char buf[] = "halt and catch fire";
  strncpy(buf, STR, strlen(STR));
  puts(buf); // prints "helloand catch fire"
  return 0;
}
```

Recommended practice in C is to check the buffer size in advance and then use `strcpy()`, alternatively `memcpy()`. 
Recommended practice in C++ is to use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 3):

From the manpage for `strncpy()`:

> **Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Either your input is shorter than the supplied length, you add the terminating null byte yourself, or it won't be there. `printf()` expects the string to be properly null terminated, and thus overruns your allocated buffer.

This only goes to show that the `n` variants of many standard functions are by no means safe. You must read their respective man pages, and specifically look for what they do when the supplied length does not suffice.