# How to change this recursive function (return a list of paths for a 3X3 matrix) into iterative function in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, recursion

the recursive function below helps to find all the paths for a 3X3 matrix, from top left to bottom right, moving either down or right. But i want to change it into an iterative function so that I can edit the function to just find a specific completed path (just 1, from top left to bottom right, by moving right or down) which sums up( sum of the values at each point equate to a set number) to a desired number eg. 12. This is especially important for a bigger matrix eg. a 9 X 1000 matrix. How do I do it?

Note for Danoran:
The values are always positive. If you look at my 3X3 matrix a, you see values of 1s, 2s and 3s. So for example, moving from 1 to 1 to 1 to 2 to 3 (goal) is a completed path and the sum is 8.

## This finds all the paths only.

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    r = []
    for j in range(3):
        r.append(i+1)
    a.append(r)
```

a = matrix

1 1 1

2 2 2

3 3 3

```
all_paths = []

def printall(currentRow, currentColumn, nums):
    if (currentRow == len(a) - 1):
        for i in range(currentColumn, len(a[0])):
            nums.append(a[currentRow][i])
        all_paths.append(nums)
        return all_paths

    if (currentColumn == len(a[0]) - 1):
        for i in range(currentRow, len(a)):
            nums.append(a[i][currentColumn])
        all_paths.append(nums)
        return all_paths

    nums.append(a[currentRow][currentColumn])
    printall(currentRow+1, currentColumn, nums[:])
    printall(currentRow, currentColumn+1, nums[:])

printall(0,0,[])

print all_paths
```

Comment: Can you define what a completed path is? Is it a path that starts top left and ends bottom right?

Comment: So you want a path returned for which the sum of the values at each point equate to a set number? not the length of the path itself

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: Sorry for the extended questions but can values be negative or are they always positive?

Comment: If you look at my 3X3 matrix a, you see values of 1s, 2s and 3s. So for example, moving from 1 to 1 to 1 to 2 to 3 (goal) is a completed path and the sum is 8.

Comment: For a 9 x 1000 matrix, the number of paths is 1007!/(999!*8!) > 2.5E19. So you'll want to find a way to eliminate a lot of paths without traversing them.

Comment: Yes you are right. Better to use iterative algorithm so that in between I can break the loop and check for desired result.  But not sure how I can make an iterative algorithm noe

Comment: this is why I asked if values can have negative weightings. If you are breaking the loop as soon as the sum has gone over the desired value you will miss solutions from negative values later down the track

Comment: OK all values are positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are R rows and C columns, you have to make R-1 down-jumps and
C-1 right-jumps. That’s invariant. The only variation is in the order of
the jumps. If we say dj=R-1 and rj=C-1, then the total number of paths
is (dj+rj)!/(dj!rj!).

So, we can simply iterate through all the unique permutations. Note that
`itertools.permutations()` will generate *all* permutations, not just
the unique ones, so we have to filter out the repeats. Of course, this
also means the run time will be proportional to (dj+rj)!, the number of
non-unique permutations. I won’t go into how to efficiently generate
unique permutations; see, for example, [Question 22431637](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431637).

In the code below, I’ve increased the number of rows to 4, to help
distinguish rows from columns.

```
from itertools import permutations

a = []
for i in range(4):
    r = []
    for j in range(3):
        r.append(i+1)
    a.append(r)

#print a   # Uncomment to trace execution

all_paths = []

def gen_all_paths(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    dj = rows - 1   # down-jumps
    rj = cols - 1   # right-jumps
    pathmix = 'd' * dj + 'r' * rj

    prev = ()
    for path in permutations(pathmix):
        if path <= prev:   # filter out repeats
            continue
        prev = path

        r, c = 0, 0
        cells = [matrix[0][0]]
        for i in path:
            if i == 'd':
                r += 1
            else:
                c += 1
            cells.append(matrix[r][c])
        #print ''.join(path), cells   # Uncomment to trace execution
        all_paths.append(cells)

gen_all_paths(a)

print all_paths
```

Comment: Still wrapping my head around this. How then will u edit this function to return a specific path for a desired sum = 13 in this 4x4 matrix?

Comment: Well, one simple way would be `if sum(cells) == 13: return cells`.