# PHP: Alphabetical permutation

Tags: php, algorithm

### I have difficult homework:

The list contains alphabetically all strings, which can form the letters A-K. The start of the list looks like this:

- ABCDEFGHIJK,
- ABCDEFGHIKJ,
- ABCDEFGHJIK,
- ABCDEFGHJKI, ...

The third string in the list is ABCDEFGHJIK. What is the list n's string?

I have made code to solve problem, but just to somewhere N value between 600 000 - 700 000. When I try to solve task with 700 000, I get 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted'. And this is the trick of the task, automatic test number 11 is 1.6 million. So there must be a simpler algorithm, but I can not find it with search engine. So what would be algorithm? My code is:

```
<?php
$number = $_REQUEST['n'];
$lettering = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K");

$counter = $number;
$done = permute($lettering, $counter);

echo $done[$number-1]."<br>";

function permute($array, $counter) {
    global $number;
    if(1 === count($array))
        return $array;
    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $item)
        foreach(permute(array_diff_key($array, array($key => $item)), $counter) as $p){
            $result[] = $item.$p;
            $counter--;
            if($counter == 0) return $result;
        }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752319/algorithm-to-list-unique-permutations-of-string-with-duplicate-letters/40756214#40756214

Comment: @MattTimmermans OP is running out of memory; he clearly has to only calculate the permutation at any given N

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others. That computes the nth permutation without forcing you to calculate the preceding ones.

Comment: @spug oh, you're right.  I didn't read the code.  But we've got lots of answers for that here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at how the permutation function is defined:

```
def permute(string):
  for each char in string
    sub <- remove char from string
    return concat(char, permute(sub))
end
```

For a string of length `L`, the `permute` function returns an array of length `L!`. Thus we can see that the list of permutations starting with the `char` at index `i` in the string starts at the `i*(L-1)!` element in the final array.

Thus the find the permutation at index `N`, we need to iteratively narrow down our search space, by finding the character to append (index given by `N / (M - 1)!`) and its corresponding substring. We remove this character from the string, append it to the result, and repeat with `N <- N % (M - 1)!` on the substring (this is the offset index into the list of permutations of this substring).

PHP code:

```
function factorial($M) {
    $N = 1;
    for (;$M > 0;$M--)
        $N *= $M;
    return $N;
}
function remove_from_str($input, $index) {
   $str1 = substr($input, 0, $index);
   $str2 = substr($input, $index+1);
   return $str1.$str2;
}

function get_permutation($input, $N) {
   $L = strlen($input);
   $result = "";
   for ($M = $L; $M > 0; $M--) {
      $F = factorial($M-1);
      $j = intval(floor($N / $F));
      $result = $result.$input[$j];
      $input = remove_from_str($input, $j);
      $N = $N % $F;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Test:

```
echo get_permutation("ABCDEFGHIJK", 1600000); // Outputs "AFEIGCDJKBH"
```

(Note: `N` here starts at 0 rather than 1)