# Program to solve Circular Combinatorics Program Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I understand how to do this by problem by hand, but I want to create a Javascript program to complete this for (c,r), with c being containers and r being rocks.

**Setting**
You have 4 indistinguishable rocks of all the same type. You also have 10 containers.  Each container can hold 0 rocks or 1 rock. All 4 rocks need to be used in every arrangement leaving 6 0s in each arrangement.

I believe there should be somewhere in the neighborhood of 210 possibilities (10!)/ (4! * (10-4)!) based on a combinations generator.

for example, these are examples of the possibilities:

```
1111000000
1110100000
1110001000
0000001111
0101010100
```

What I am looking for is a javascript function that will spit out the 210 arrays such that it is `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]` with an input of a number of rocks and containers.

Comment: Basically you're looking for all binary numbers from 0 - 1023 ( 2 ^ 10 digits - 1 ) that have 4 bits set.  Quick and dirty way will be to loop from 0 to 1023, convert this number to binary ( ie, `toString(2)` ) and count the number of 1's.  If there are four 1's, keep the result, otherwise move on to the next number.

Comment: @JonTrent I posted an answer based on your idea which I find fantastic. if you want to post this as an answer yourself, please do! It's your idea

Comment: @blex, it's all you!  You did the heavy lifting.  Plus your approach to splitting on the 1's to count the 1's is a neat approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried @JonTrent's way to do it (counting from `0` to `2^c - 1`), this is a really clever way to do it:

```js
function getCombinations(c, r) {
  const max = Math.pow(2, c);
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    const binary = i.toString(2);
    if (binary.split("1").length - 1 === r) {
      res.push(
        binary.padStart(c, '0')
              .split('')
              .map(n => parseInt(n, 10))
      );
    }
  }
  return res;
}

const res = getCombinations(10, 4);
// [
//  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
//  [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
//  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
//  ...
// ]

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${res.map(x => x.join('')).join('\n')}</pre>`;
console.log(`${res.length} combinations found!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied the answer from here, [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

And then add as many space as you want into the input array. Try any solution you want from that post then.

```js
function permutator(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
    }

    return results;
  }

  return permute(inputArr);
}

console.log(permutator(['a', ' ', 'b', 'c']))
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, however. If we imagine there are 3 containers and 2 rocks, (`permutator(['1', '1', '0'])`), we get duplicate combinations

Comment: oh, then search `permutation` with unique result then. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264376/get-all-the-possible-unique-permutations

Answer (score 0):

You could seach for the next element to swap and reorder the right left over value to the most right side.

```js
function perm(string) {
    var array = [...string],
        l = array.length - 1,
        r = array.length - 1;
    
    // either starts with zero from end or with one and get only ones
    while (array[l] === '0') l--;
    while (array[l] === '1') l--;
    if (l < 0) return;
    [array[l], array[l + 1]] = [array[l + 1], array[l]];
    while (r > ++l) {
        if (array[l] === '1') {
            [array[l], array[r]] = [array[r], array[l]];
            r--;
        }
    }
    return array.join('');
}

var string = '0000001111',
    i = 0,
    log = document.getElementById('out');
    
do out.innerHTML += `${(++i).toString().padStart(3, ' ')} ${string}\n`;
while (string = perm(string));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function circular(c, r) {
    let arrs = [[]];
    for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        let len = arrs.length;
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            arr = arrs.shift();
            if (arr.filter((el) => el === 0).length < c - r) {
                arrs.push(arr.concat([0]));
            }
            if (arr.filter((el) => el === 1).length < r) {
                arrs.push(arr.concat([1]));
            }
        }
    }
    return arrs;
}

console.log(circular(3, 1));
console.log(circular(10, 4).length);
```