# Error "'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
struct PhaseShiftPin {
    int _PSPpin_index;      //PSP = Phase Shift Pin
    int _PSPvalue;
    char _PSPname[512];
};
struct PhaseShiftPin *_PhaseShiftPin[500000];
int p3int = 0;
strcpy ( _PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue, p3int );
```

The above code is just part of my full code.
When I compiled my full program happened an error **strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast**
which is at line

```
strcpy ( _PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue, p3int );
```

I have referred to the post at here [makes pointer from integer without a cast with strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891012/makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast-with-strcpy,but) after I tried to use strncpy and follow the method showed in the post I still fail in compilation.Hope you can guide me with my problem.Thanks.

Comment: you try to copy something on a int and not on a char *

Comment: Looks like you're trying to copy one int to another. Can't you just go: p3int = _PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue;

Comment: Please go through [This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) link again and have a look on type of arguments.

Comment: try `char *p3int = NULL` instead of `int p3int = 0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of strcpy you can see

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

But your `_PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue` is an integer and `p3int` also.

you can use memcpy

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

strcpy ( &(_PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue), &(p3int), sizeof(p3int) );
```

or simply as said in a comment

```
_PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue =  p3int;
```

if you try to copy `p3int` into  `_PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue`

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` is inappropriate for this problem. It takes two arguments. The first is a pointer to `char`, and the second is a pointer to `const char`. It then copies the string pointed to by the second pointer into the memory pointed to by the first.

In your case, you are not copying a string, you are copying an int. Your last line should be:

```
_PhaseShiftPin[i]->_PSPvalue = p3int;
```

However, the C99 standard reserves identifiers that begin with an underscore ('_') followed by an uppercase letter or another underscore for the implementation. Therefore you must not name your identifiers this way.