# How fast is strn*() compared to str*()?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should you use strncpy instead of strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)

I'm reading a book about computers/cryptographic etc. And often the writer use thing such as `strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));` instead of `strcpy(dest, src);` it makes no much sense for me.. Well, I'm a professional programmer.

The question is: It make really a real difference? real applications use something like this?

Comment: I can't see why `strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));` would be faster than `strcpy(dest, src);`.

Comment: @Mysticial It's the same speed (though the strlen adds an overhead of using it).  Speed is not why it's used.  Defending against buffer overflows is why it's preferred.  (`strncpy` is the same speed as `strcpy` I mean.  The internals are the same speed, assuming the same amount of characters are copied are made.)  By the way, the third parameter shouldn't be the string length, but rather the size of the dest buffer (or perhaps the size minus 1).

Comment: @Mystical Just realized that you are not the question asker, and thus half of my previous comment is just rambling.  Going to leave the previous comment though in case the asker does find it useful, and it's close to length limit so can't write this note there :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The author is almost certainly abusing the `strn*` functions.  Unfortunately, there is almost never a good reason to use `strn*` functions, since they don't actually do what you want.

Let's take a look at `strcpy` and `strncpy`:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

The `strcpy` function copies `src` into `dest`, including a trailing `\0`.  It is only rarely useful:

1. Unless you know the source string fits in the destination buffer, you have a buffer overflow.  Buffer overflows are security hazards, they can crash your program, and cause it to behave incorrectly.
2. If you *do* know the size of the source string and destination buffer, you might as well use `memcpy`.

By comparison, the `strncpy` copies at most `n` bytes of `src` into `dest` and then pads the rest with `\0`.  It is only rarely useful:

1. Unless you know the source string is smaller than the destination buffer, you cannot be certain that the resulting buffer will be nul-terminated.  This can cause errors elsewhere in the program, if you assume the result is nul-terminated.
2. If you do know the source string is smaller, again, you might as well use `memcpy`.
3. You can simply terminate the string after you call `strncpy`, but are you sure that you want to silently truncate the result?  I'd imagine most of the time, you'd rather have an error message.

### Why do these functions exist?

The `strcpy` function is occasionally handy, but it is mostly a relic of an era where people did not care very much about validating input.  Feeding a string that is too large to a program would crash it, and the advice was "don't do that".

The `strncpy` function is useful when you want to transmit data in fixed-size fields, and you don't want to put garbage in the remainder of the field.  This is mostly a relic of an era where people used fixed-size fields.

So you will rarely see `strcat` or `strncpy` in modern C software.

### A worse problem

However, your example combines the worst of both worlds.  Let's examine this piece of source code:

```
strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));
```

This copies `src` into `dest`, **without** a `\0` terminator and **without** bounds checking.  It combines the worst aspect of `strcpy` (no bounds checking) with the worst aspect of `strncpy` (no terminator).  If you see code like this, run away.

### How to work with strings

Good C code typically uses one of a few options for working with strings:

1. Use fixed buffers and `snprintf`, as long as you don't mind fixed buffers.
2. Use bounded string functions like `strlcpy` and `strlcat`.  These are BSD extensions.
3. Use a custom string point which tracks string lengths, and write your own functions using `memcpy` and `malloc`.

Comment: "A worse problem" - specifically, `strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));` is exactly equivalent to `memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src))`. So the only reason I can think of for writing it is that you don't know what you're doing, since you're writing the code to look like a string operation, when really it isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

If that code is a verbatim copy from the book, the author either does not know C or is not a security specialist or both.

It could also be that he's using a misconfigured compiler, explicitly prohibiting the use of certain known to be potentially unsafe functions. And it's a questionable practice when the compiler cannot distinguish safe from unsafe from potentially unsafe and is just getting in the way all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the strn family is to prevent you from overflowing buffers.  If you're passed data from a caller and blindly trust that it's properly null-terminated and won't overflow the buffer you're copying it to,  your going to got owned by a buffer overrun attack.

The efficiency difference is negligible.  The strn family might be *slightly* slower as it needs to keep checking that you're not overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src)); is the same as strcpy(dest, src); so there's no difference here, but..

Strcpy can lead to security holes, since you don't know how long the strings are. Somebody clever can overwrite something on your server using this.

Comment: If `src` is not `\0`-terminated, `strncpy(dst, src, strlen(src))` clearly won't be of any help security-wise compared to plain `strcpy(dst, src)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use of strncpy against strcpy has little to do with its execution speed but strncpy strongly lowers the possibility of buffer overflow attacks.
In C, the pointers are most powerful but they also make the system vulnerable.

Following excerpt from a good Hack-Proofing book might help you.

*Many overflow bugs are a result of bad string manipulation. Calls such as
strcpy() do not check the length of a string before copying it. The result is
that a buffer overflow may occur. It is expected that a NULL terminator will
be present. In one sense, the attacker relies on this bug in order to exploit a
machine; however, it also means that the attacker’s injected buffer also must
be free of NULL characters. If the attacker inserts a NULL character, the
string copy will be terminated before the entire payload can be inserted.*

Comment: "strncpy strongly lowers the possibility of buffer overflow attacks" the code in the question demonstrates that it doesn't, but that there exist programmers who think the `n` is a kind of magic pixie dust that improves their code.