# "this" pointer becomes null c++

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a C++ Qt static library with two classes - *dataprocthread* and *calcvalue*. In the first one, when I call a method from an instance of *calcvalue*, pointer `this` (which references to *dataprocthread* class) suddenly becomes `null`.

This is *dataprocthread.h*:

```
class DataProcThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        DataProcThread(int sarray[9], int val);

    signals:
        workDone(int result);

    private:            
        int _sarray[9];
        int _val;
        void run();
};
```

*dataprocthread.cpp*:

```
DataProcThread::DataProcThread(int sarray[9], int val)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        _sarray[x] = sarray[x];
    }
    _val = val;
}

void DataProcThread::run()
{
    CalcValue* cv = new CalcValue();
    int myval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        myval = cv->processData(this->_val);
        if (this->_sarray[0] != myval)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    emit workDone(intValue);
}
```

*calcvalue.h*:

```
class CalcValue
{
    public:
        CalcValue();
        int processData(int someval);
};
```

*calcvalue.cpp*:

```
CalcValue::CalcValue()
{
}

int processData(int someval)
{
    //do something and return int value
}
```

When I run this code, it suddenly recieves signal "Segmentation fault". Using debugger, I found that the problem in `DataProcThread::run()` function: when I call `cv->processData` function, all works good. But on the next line (`if (this->_sarray[0] != myval)`), `this` pointer becomes `null` (I can see it in Locals window), therefore, I can't access `this->_sarray` variable.

In case it is important, that's how I start the thread (from another class outside my library):

```
DataProcThread* thread = new DataProcThread(sarray, val);
QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(workDone(int)), this, SLOT(collectWork(int)));
thread->start();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: i guess `this->_sarray[0]` is null.

Comment: Before `this` becomes `null`, I can see `sarray` values in Locals window.

Comment: Maybe your processData is writing over memory

Comment: Hmm, that sounds possible. I'll try to look into this. Can `strcpy`, `char**` or `strtoll` do this?

Comment: Are you sure that the `DataProcThread` object hasn't been destroyed already?  Or that you're you're not trying to invoke `run` on a null pointer?

Comment: I don't think so, there are no place that deletes `DataProcThread`.

Comment: If all is well before calling `processData`, and things are broken afterwards, then maybe perhaps `processData` could be possibly doing something suspicious? Just a wild guess.

Comment: @ahawkthomas strcpy can, you can eliminate this hypothesis by eliminating code from processData, Visual Studio in debugging mode is able to show you exact line where any buffer overrun happens

Comment: Deleting an object has absolutely nothing to do with a pointer to said object becoming null. One is neither necessary nor sufficient for the other.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I really meant: does some object that's already been destroyed have a member pointing to it.  If a debug runtime zeroes freed memory, then that member could have the value 0, and accidentally attempting to invoke a method through that pointer then would lead to a null `this` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as was pointed out in comments, took place in `processData` function: it was writing over memory.

I simply used [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) instead of [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) and the problem gone ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy) is a good explanation about this).

Comment: I hope you're aware that `strncpy` has its own pitfalls.

Comment: Yes, but it fits for my tasks.

Comment: std::vector<int>& and such can avoid the use of those dangerous C functions, and std::unique_ptr or QScopedPointer will also avoid the use of the raw pointer.