# sizeof operation in c & strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am writing a C program to understand strings and pointers. Everything works except the sizeof operation for a char* [] and char**[].

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
  puts("");
  char src[]= "rabbit";
  char* src2[] = {"rabbit","dog","monkey"};
  char* src3[] = {"fish","horse","dolphin"};
  char** src4[] = {src2,src3};
  int i,j;

  printf("Size of the char array only is %d\n",sizeof(src));
  printf("Size of the array of string pointers only is %d\n", sizeof(&src2));
  printf("Size of the array of pointers to string pointers only %d\n\n", sizeof(src4));

   puts("Single char array is:");
   for(i = 0; i<sizeof(src)-1; i++){
     printf("%c,",src[i]);
   }

  puts ("\n");

  puts("Array of strings:");
  puts(src2[0]);
  puts(src2[1]);
  puts(src2[2]);
  puts("");

  puts("Printing the char** [] contents ");

  for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(j=0; j < 3;j++){
      puts(src4[i][j]);
     }
  }

  puts("");

  return 0;

}
```

So how do get the number of elements in char* [] and char** [] ?
Also on another note if I for example declare char*[] src2 = {"rabbit","dog","monkey"}; as only char*[] m_src. Then do I have to malloc space for each element I add into this array ? for example

If I had instead done

```
    // Code segment changed for char*[]
    char* m_src[];
    // could I do this
    m_src = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    m_src[0] = "rabbit";
    m_src[1] = "dog";
    m_src[2] = "monkey";

    /* Even more is there a way to dynamically add elements to the
    array like mallocing space for a single element at a time and tacking it onto the
    array char* m_src? */
```

Comment: You can't do `char* m_src[]`; . Either do intialization at the first place, else you will need to mention the number of elements of the array. Or, `char **m_src;` and do dynamic allocation later.

Comment: Use `%zu`, not `%d` to print a `size_t` value such as the result of `sizeof`. If your implementation doesn't support `%zu`, use `%lu` and cast the value to `unsigned long`: `printf("sizeof foo = %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof foo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How do I get the number of elements in `char *[]` and `char **[]` ?

```
printf("Number of elements in char* src2[]: %d\n", (sizeof src2)/(sizeof src2[0]) );
```

Same technique for `char **[]` too,

```
printf("Number of elements in char** src4[]: %d\n", (sizeof src4)/(sizeof src4[0]) );
```

---

### How do I alloc dynamic Array to point to C-style-strings ?

```
char **d_alloc;
d_alloc = malloc(3 * sizeof *d_alloc);
if(d_alloc == NULL)
{
    printf("malloc failed !");
    return -1; 
}
d_alloc[0] = "Created";
d_alloc[1] = "Dynamic";
d_alloc[2] = "Arrays";
printf("%s %s %s\n",d_alloc[0], d_alloc[1], d_alloc[2]);
```

---

### Why the below code doesn't work ?

```
char** src5;
src5 = malloc(3 * sizeof(src5)); 
puts("Dynamically allotted char*"); 
src5[0] = "lion"; 
src5[1] = "shark"; 
printf("%s %s\n",src5[0],src[1]);
```

You wanted to dynamically allocate space for `char *`. So, pass `malloc()` the `sizeof *src5` and not the `sizeof src5`. `src5` is the pointer to `char *`'s , you will use later to access the dynamically allocated space.

```
src5 = malloc(3 * sizeof *src5);
```

`*src5` is of type `char *`.

Comment: I wrote something similar like:                                          ' char** src5;
  src5 = malloc(3 * sizeof(*src5));                                       puts("Dynamically allotted char**");
  src5[0] = "lion";
  src5[1] = "shark";
  printf("%s %s\n",src5[0],src[1]);'                                this segfaults if I try to print more than 1 element. Any ideas why ? if I try to print the elements individually it works?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest: Answer updated to answer the query you posted as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is only working that way because you're creating a static string, assigning it at creation.

`sizeof` will show the size of the data type normally (if you use the pointer method), even after you `malloc()` the memory. Execute this code to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
        char *string;
        char *dynamic;
        dynamic = malloc(10 * sizeof(*dynamic));
        if (!dynamic)
            /* Error, malloc() failed. */
            return 1;

        /* Copy something into the string. */
        strcpy(dynamic, "testing");

        printf("sizeof char pointer:     %d\n", sizeof(string));
        printf("sizeof char:             %d\n", sizeof(*string));
        printf("dynamic:                 %s\n", dynamic);
        printf("sizeof dynamic pointer:  %d\n", sizeof(dynamic));
        printf("sizeof dynamic:          %d\n", sizeof(*dynamic));

        free(dynamic);
        return 0;
}
```

For your string lengths, you're probably after `strlen()`. When you `malloc` you also need to check whether it returns `NULL` (if it fails) and also `free` later. The size is usually a buffer, so to store 50 char in something you're allocating with `malloc`, you'd use something like this (though the sizeof part isn't needed for `char`):

```
char *str;
str = malloc(50 * sizeof(*str));
```

Comment: `src2` is array of pointer-to-char. Believe he was looking for ways to dynamically allocate pointer-to-char and not `char`. `malloc(10 * sizeof(*dynamic)` will only do dynamic alloc of `char`'s

Comment: Also, you can modify your `strcpy()` to `strncpy(dynamic, "testing", 9)`. As you have allocated only 10 `char`'s to be pointed to by `dynamic`. **[Why you should do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)**

Comment: `strncpy()` has its own problems, you have to make sure you choose the length carefully. If it's a string literal with a length less than the buffer, `strcpy` is acceptable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/870135/2441252

Comment: How about `memset(dynamic, '\0', 10);` followed by `strncpy(dynamic, "testing", 9);` followed by `dynamic[9]='\0';` ?
The link you posted details out problems with `strncpy()` which can be worked out. Can you justify how `strcpy()` is better than `strncpy()` ?

Comment: I didn't say better, it's just acceptable in certain circumstances. Like when you know that a literal string that you're hardcoding is shorter in length than the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to divide the size of the array, in bytes, by the size of a single element:

```
int size = sizeof(src3) / sizeof(*src3);
int size = sizeof(src4) / sizeof(*src4);
```