# How to modify the content in one single string in C?

Tags: c, arrays

It's simple question but i just couldn't figure out. I've been trying to make an approach to replace the content of one string by part of it's content like, replace "He is a boy" to "is a boy" as follow:

```
int main() {
    char array[] = "he is a boy";
    strcpy(array, &array[3]);
    printf("%s\n", array);
}
```

But the program just stopped at strcpy statement.
Is there any problem using strcpy or any other method to achieve the same purpose??
BTW, I'm using X-code on my mac. Thx~

Comment: please avoid strcpy and instad use strncpy. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot use `strcpy()` when the source and destination overlap. This is clearly stated in the manual page:

> The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.

You can use [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove), but then you have to specify the length and probably deal with termination issues yourself since it's a general-purpose memory-manipulation function, and not designed for strings specifically.

In your case since you're copying the tail, we can just include the termination and be fine:

```
int main(void) {
    char array[] = "he is a boy";
    memmove(array, array + 3, 9);
    printf("%s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```