# What is wrong with this code? (Basic C Code)

Tags: c, syntax-error, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "kitty";
    const int a_length = strlen(a);

    char *my_kitty = malloc(a_length);

    strcpy(my_kitty, a);

    printf("%s\n", my_kitty);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Null check for malloc?
I am kind of confused about pointers.

Comment: What is it giving as an error? Other than that, your `malloc` isn't allocating enough space for the String and the NULL terminator.

Comment: What error do you get? Is it compile-time or run-time?

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: I am not getting any error running your code.
https://ideone.com/aTcmS8

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to allocate an extra +1 for the null terminator!

```
char *my_kitty = malloc(a_length + 1);
... strcpy()
```

<del>my_kitty[a_length] = 0;</del>

(as per the comments, `strcpy` will also copy the null terminator)

**Edit**

[Just be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/314291) when using either `strcpy` or `strncpy` - the former is prone to buffer overflows if the null terminator is omitted, and the latter, although safer in the sense that it will limit the number of copied characters, will omit the null terminator if there is insufficient length remaining.

Comment: Do you have to do `my_kitty[a_length] = 0;`? Isn't it automatic with `strcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `strcpy`. Instead,

```
strncpy(my_kitty, a, a_length + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought that strlen was on string.h

```
NAME
     strlen, strnlen -- find length of string

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocated space for the text part of the string, but not for its zero character terminator. The space required for a null terminated string is given by strlen(string) + 1.