# String copy error in C

Tags: c

I don't understand why `str1` is changing here. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (){
    char str1[]="stackoverflowwwwwww";//str1
    char str2[] = "stackoverflow";
    char str3[40];
    char str4[40];
    char str5[] = "asdfgh";
    strcpy(str2, str1);
    strcpy(str3, "successful");
    strcpy(str4, str5);
    printf("str1: %s\nstr2: %s\nstr3:%s\nstr4:%s\n", str1, str2, str3, str4);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
str1: www
str2: stackoverflowwwwwww
str3: successful
str4: asdfgh
```

Why is `str1` changing here?

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior*. `strcpy(str2, str1);` How large is that target buffer? The answer to your question is the answer to *that* question.

Comment: @Cplusminus_is_coming Can you support that expectation with a quote from its specification (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) ? Or are you thinking of strncpy with appropriate parameters?

Comment: Could you provide the value of the address difference str1-str2 in your environment? Either use a debugger or print the pointer values.

Comment: If you're genuinely curious why this happens *in your specific circumstance*, use your debugger. There is no *defined* reason as far as the language is concerned. You left the safety of that reservation as soon as you invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: @artm: If you remove the C++ tag, you should also edit the title.

Comment: [`strcpy` is not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23317646/995714). Here you're writing beyond the destination buffer's size

Comment: use `[40]` instead of `[]` .`strcpy` is safe enough

Answer (score 2):

Your program contains a buffer overflow. `str2` is a buffer, its size is 14bytes (the length of "stackoverflow" + the terminating NULL character). When you execute `strcpy(str2, str1)` you are overflowing that buffer since `str1` is longer than 14bytes. `strcpy` has no way of knowing the size of the buffer, so (by its definition) it blindly copies from one buffer to the other.

#### Buffer overflow on the stack

Now, why does this alter `str1`? Well, because when `strcpy` copies more chars than the destination buffer's size, these chars must go somewhere.
Since both `str2` and `str1` are allocated on the stack, they are placed right next to each other. So, when `strcpy` copies onto `str2` and overflows its size, it will move on to whatever's next to it in the memory - in your case that's `str1`.

So, the last characters `strcpy` is copying - the last few characters in `str1` - are copied back onto the beginning of `str1`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the destination `str2` is shorter than string length `str1` therefore this is an undefined behaviour.

But to understand why this happens, consider the following.

When I print out the memory addresses of the string, before any modification of your code in my system it is like this.

```
printf("str1: %p (%d)  \nstr2: %p (%d)\n", str1, strlen (str1),  str2, strlen (str2));

str1: 0x7ffd394e85d0 (19)  
str2: 0x7ffd394e85c2 (13)
str1: wwwww
str2: stackoverflowwwwwww
str3:successful
str4:asdfgh
```

Note the address of `str1` and `str2`. `str2` starts first (lower address) and `0x7ffd394e85d0 - 0x7ffd394e85c2 = e`, which is 13 in decimal, the exact length of the string.

Therefore the initial layout is

```
Initial layout
0x7ffd394e85c2               0x7ffd394e85d0
str2                         str1
|                            | 
|                            |
V                            V
s t a c k o v e r f l o w \0 s t a c k o v e r f l o w w w w w w w \0
```

When the string is being copied from `str1` to `str2`, `strcpy` will align and copy strings as follows. Here the end of `str2` buffer gets violated.

```
When being copied
0x7ffd394e85c2               0x7ffd394e85d0
str2                         str1
|                            | 
|                            |
V                            V
s t a c k o v e r f l o w \0 s t a c k o v e r f l o w w w w w w w \0
s t a c k o v e r f l o w w  w w w w w \0
```

After copy the state is as follows

```
After copy
0x7ffd394e85c2              0x7ffd394e85d0
str2                        str1
|                           | 
|                           |
V                           V
s t a c k o v e r f l o w w w w w w w \0 v e r f l o w w w w w w w \0
```

Now `str1` points to the beginning of the buffer starting with a 'w' and it has five consecutive 'w's until it reaches '\0'. Therefore the C string pointed by `str1` now is "wwwww", as you see in your output.

**Note** that this is for my system where I get five consecutive 'w's. In other systems, the compiler may generate code which has a few blank bytes between the end of `str2` and the beginning of `str1`, therefore they can have a varying number of 'w's. Also, note that, as this is an undefined behaviour, and the storage layout of the two strings are not defined, the output can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The result of this program is unknown, maybe various,because:
str3 and str4 are used without initialized, you had better initialize like this:

```
char str3[40] = {0};
char str4[40] = {0};
```

So, the borders which obey the size 40 will be under control of a programmer.

Obviously, the space of str2 cause problems if execute 'strcpy(str2, str1);'