# Advantages of strncmp over strcmp?

Tags: c, c-standard-library

Seems `strncmp` is usually recommended than `strcmp`, what are the advantages? I think it could be related to security. If this is the case, is it still applicable if one of the input string is known to be literal constant, like `"LiteralString"`?

**UPDATE:**
I mean under the same user scenario where whole strings need to be compared, and `strncmp` can be used as below. I am wondering it makes sense or not.

```
strncmp(inputString, "LiternalString", strlen("LiternalString"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should you use strncpy instead of strcpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)

Answer (score 25):

The problem with `strcmp` is that sometimes, if by mistake, arguments that are passed are not valid C-strings (meaning that p1 or p2 is not terminated with a null character i.e. not [NULL-terminated String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)), then, strcmp continues comparing until it reaches non-accessible memory and crashes or sometimes results to an unexpected behaviour.

Using `strncmp` you can limit the search, so that it doesn't reach non-accessible memory.

But, from that, it should not be concluded that `strcmp` is insecure to use. Both the functions work well in the way they are intended to work. Programmer should read `man` page for that function before using it and must be sincere enough while passing parameters to such library functions.

You can also read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy) which contains an almost similar question.

Comment: My question now is: what is the value to set for n, to ensure i won't reach non- accessable memory, and still ensure to get any valid input.

Comment: `strcmp` function is to compare strings, it you pass buffers that are not strings, what semantics to you expect ?

Comment: @Zaibis,  to set a value for `n`, one of the parameter must be a valid string whose `length` can be assigned to `n`  as you did in the UPDATE part of your question.

Comment: "*until it reaches non-accessible memory and crashes.*" -- It might not crash. It is just Undefined Behavior

Comment: @CoolGuy, That's cent percent true, it may result undefined behaviour instead of crashing

Comment: @chqrlie , Answerer has updated the answer. He/she meant to say not C-strings,i.e, not NUL-terminated strings

Comment: The whole "if by mistake" idea is not convincing. `strncmp` is not a hardening function. It's semantically different from `strcmp` and has different uses.

Comment: @R.. , I have mentioned that. Its actually programmer's fault. Both the functions works well in the way they are intended to work

Comment: With this logic, most string functions from standard library, such as `strlen` can never be used because if "by mistake" the string arguments may not contain nul-terminator.

Comment: @P.P. I've never said that `strcmp` could never be used. Its just need proper arguments (supplying NULL-terminated strings) to get expected result. And yes this is true for all string functions from standard library, such as `strlen`.

Answer (score 17):

`strncmp` does not have "advantages over `strcmp`"; rather they solve different problems. `strcmp` is for determining if two strings are equal (and if not, possibly how to order/sort them with respect to each other). `strncmp` is (mainly) for determining whether a string begins with a particular prefix. For example:

```
if (strncmp(str, "--option=", 9)==0)
```

will determine if `str` begins with `"--option="`. This cannot be achieved by `strcmp` without either modifying the string to be checked (which may not be a valid operation) or making a useless copy of it. It also cannot be achieved with `memcmp` unless you already know `str` points to an object at least 9 bytes in length; otherwise the call to `memcmp` would have undefined behavior.

There are other usage cases for `strncmp` too, such as working with non-C-string data.

Answer (score 10):

It all depends on your use-cases. Use [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) if you only need to compare a fixed number of characters, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) if you need to compare a whole string.

That's about it.

Comment: to compare an initial substring, you can also use `memcmp`.

Comment: @chqrlie True, but then care has to be take to make sure that the sub-string isn't longer than the full string.

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg said - `memcmp` is not legal in this case unless you know the string you're comparing is at least as long as the substring.

Answer (score 5):

> ... under the same user scenario where **whole strings** need to be compared, ...

```
 strncmp(inputString, "LiternalString", strlen("LiternalString"));
```

Consider the case where string `inputString` is longer than the *string literal*.

```
const char *inputString = "LiternalString_XYZ";
int cmp = strncmp(inputString, "LiternalString", strlen("LiternalString"));
printf("%d\n", cmp); // prints 0.
```

But OP wanted **whole strings** compared.

```
const char *inputString = "LiternalString_XYZ";
int cmp = strcmp(inputString, "LiternalString");
printf("%d\n", cmp); // prints non-zero.
```

---

**Conclusion to OP's direct question**

> I am wondering it makes sense or not.

No.  To compare **whole strings**, `strncmp()` fails to consistently provide the correct result.  Use `strcmp()`.

---

**Further**

`strncmp(s1,s2,n)` can limit the search, so that it doesn't reach non-accessible memory **if** `n` was properly computed - which was not done in OP's code and problematic to do right when the best `n` is different for `s1` and `s2`.

The size limit `n` applies to both `s1` and `s2` thus making this function useful for comparing prefixes, but not `"safer".

In OP's case, there is no reason to limit the search due to "safety" on account of the string length of the *string literal* as *string literals* **always** contains a terminating *null character*.

If anything, `n` should have been based on some property of `inputString`.

Code like `strncmp(s1, string_literal, strlen(s1))` is functionally incorrect as the compare misses the *null character*.  A wee bit better is `strncmp(s1, string_literal, strlen(s1)+1)`, but that is functionally the same  as the simpler `strcmp(s1, string_literal)` with no reduction in "safety".

---

The below offer some improve "safety" in case `foo()` did not properly form  *strings*, but can provide the wrong answer if `N != M` as above.

```
char s1[N];
foo(s1); // populate s1 somehow
int cmp = strncmp(s1, string_literal, sizeof s1);

char s1[N];
char s2[M];
foo(s1); // populate s1 somehow
foo(s2); // populate s2 somehow
int cmp = strncmp(s1, s2, min(sizeof s1, sizeof s2));
```

Yet in those cases, the problem is in `foo()`, not here.
For me, if `foo()` was so questionable, I'd use the following

```
s1[sizeof s1 - 1] = '\0';
s2[sizeof s2 - 1] = '\0';
int cmp = strcmp(s1, s2);
```

or detect that `foo()` did not form a *string*.

```
char s1[N];
foo(s1);
if (memchr(s1, '\0', sizeof s1) == NULL) Oops();
```

Moral of the story: `strncmp()` is not a "safer" version of `strcmp()`.  It is a tool for a different job: comparing string prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Just post an anti-strncmp use case here. 
Think about the following code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    //I want to list all files under current folder, include hidden files.
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dp;
    char * file_name;
    dir = opendir(".");
    while ((dp=readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("debug: %s\n", dp->d_name);
        if ( !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") )
        //It doesn't work if you replace strcmp with strncmp here.
        //if ( !strncmp(dp->d_name, ".", 1) || !strncmp(dp->d_name, "..", 2) )  
        {
        } else {
            file_name = dp->d_name;
            printf("file_name: \"%s\"\n",file_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int ret1, ret2;
char dev1[]  = { "ABC" };
char dev2[4] = { "ABC" };

dev2[3] = 'D';
ret1 = strncmp(dev1,dev2,strlen(dev1));  // # of characters
ret2 = strncmp(dev1,dev2,sizeof(dev1));  // # of characters plus '\0'
```

assume: dev1 is null terminated and dev2 is probably not. ret1 = 0 (false positive result), rather than ret2=-1 (valid result)

fazit: strncmp is not just a safer way for strcmp. depends on how you make use of it.

i´d use strcmp on strings, and strncmp on substring search.

Answer (score -2):

strcmp could lead to storage volation and segmentation fault in case where one of arguments is not null-terminated string. Take a look [why you should use strncpy instead of strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy). Consequences are unlikely to happen in strcmp, but issue is the same. strnxxx function family try to prevent reading/writing not acquired memory.

Disadvantage of using strn is extra compare and decrement operation on counter.

In few words: strncmp is safer then strcmp, but it is slower too.

Comment: `strncmp` and `strcmp` have different semantics. Using one for the other is not a hardening method.  `strncpy` is different from `strcpy` in ways most programmers are unaware of. To prevent buffer overflow by *limiting* the copy to the destination buffer, `strlcpy` is **much** better than *strncpy*.  If your system does not have it, implementing your own version is recommended.

Comment: Strncmp only prevents an overrun if you know that only one of the strings might not be null-terminated and you know which of the two strings it is. And if you use strncmp as a replacement for strcmp, you might be opening yourself up to having a substring match come back true when you didn’t want that.

Answer (score -3):

I could see only one advantage, that strncmp will take slightly less time to execute than strcmp as we will always compare prefix of string to comapre rather than entire string.

I don't think that there is any security aspect involved in strcmp and strncmp algorithm. They are same except that in strncmp only first 'n' characters are compared.