# Comparing Strings and pointers

Tags: c, c89

I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers and strings in C for a class I'm taking. In the below example, g_reservations[][] is a global variable (not ideal, I know, but I cant change that).

error:
Warning C4047   'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char' EconoAirBeta    ... 299

*passenger is a pointer, so do create a pointer to the global? That seems unnecessary...

how do i make this work? I feel I'm missing some incredibly easy concept my brain cant seem to grasp....

```
unsigned int FindSeatWithPassenger(const char *passengerName)
{
    unsigned int seat = 0;
    for (seat = 0; seat < NUM_SEATS; ++seat)
    {
        if ( strncmp(passengerName, g_reservations[seat][0], NAME_LENGTH) != 0) //error here with global variable
        {
            return seat;
            break;
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Global declaration:

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 10
#define NAME_BUFFER_LENGTH ( NAME_LENGTH + 1 )
char g_reservations[NUM_SEATS][NAME_BUFFER_LENGTH];
```

Comment: Coyld you please show how `g_reservations[seat][0]` matrix is declared ? Is it `char**` ?

Comment: edited above to include global declaration...

Comment: Use `g_reservations[seat]` in `strncmp`. The second index denotes the characters of the string you want to compare.

Comment: Note: `stncmp` returns 0 when equal!

Comment: Note: at the end you are formally returning a char, whereas the function should return an usigned int. At the end, use `return 0;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - Thanks! that did it! (like i said, my brain just got hung up)
TY also for the return note...

Comment: Aside:  Looks like OP is begin encouraged to use `strncmp()` over `strcmp()`.  Recommend this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192078/2410359).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wrong type**

Just as the error says.

`g_reservations[seat][0]` is a `char`.

`int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)` expects a `char *` for `s2`.

Use `&g_reservations[seat][0]` or simply `g_reservations[seat]`

```
strncmp(passengerName, g_reservations[seat], NAME_LENGTH)
```