# Remove first char from received buffer

Tags: c

I have a message which I receive in the `rmsg` variable. If the first character in this buffer is '1', I want to remove this char and send the rest of the message.

So is there any way to do something like this:

```
if(rmsg[0]=='1')

//remove the first character in rmsg
strncpy(newbuf,rmsg,rmsglen)
```

If this is not the right direction could anyone show me how?

Comment: just to be clear? You need to remove the first char, then send the new string?

Comment: To clarify more, are you going to use the string (with the first character removed) after sending it?

Comment: `'1'` is not a string, but a `char`. These are very different datatypes in C and any other language. Using the correct terms will help others to understand what you ask.

Comment: Is your problem solved, @codeheadache?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it is what you want to achieve in this case:

```
if (rmsg[0] == '1') 
    memmove(rmsg, rmsg+1, strlen(rmsg));
```

Here, after using `memmove()` function like I posted above, your `rmsg` string will contain its **previous content without first char** (which is == '1'), so now you can just send it easily wherever you want.

Live demo: http://ideone.com/1dJjAn
More about `memmove()` func: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second char as base address for sending and decrease the length by 1:

```
   if (rmsglen > 0 && rmsg[0]=='1')
      send (&rmsg[1], rmsglen-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy the string to new string expect the first character you can do something like this -

```
char rmsg[]="1 I can go";
char *newbuf;
newbuf=malloc(strlen(msg));
if(rmsg[0]=='1')
{
    strncpy(newbuf,&rmsg[1],rmsglen-1);  
}
free(newbuf);
```

Small example -https://ideone.com/IotuBy

Comment: A couple of thoughts: The `+1` isn't needed since the copied string will be shorter and there's thus enough space for the trailing NULL. Why do you think there's a space after the `1`? And why do you think OP want's to skip it, he doesn't say so? Also, [avoid `strcpy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy), the length is already known (`rmsglen`).

Comment: @DarkDust  The space after `1` was just my thought in case if it is there. And about `+1` yes that was not needed. And I didn't notice `rmsglen` thus didn't took that in account. But thanks for your input I edited my answer.