# Heap corruption error while trying to free a two-dimentional array

Tags: c, string, free, heap-corruption

My program receives a two-dimentional array of strings. After it does what it should do i try to free the memory allocated for the strings but i get a Heap corruption error when i try to do so.
Here's my code:

```
printf("Please enter the number of lines:");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        lines = (char**)malloc(length*sizeof(char*));//allocating memory for the array of strings "lines".
        if (lines == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Not enough memory.");
            return 0;
        }
        getchar();//needed in order to use "gets".
        printf("Please enter your lines:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            printf("%d.", i);
            gets(buffer);//user inserts the string "buffer".
            lines[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));//allocating memory for the strings in the array according to the ength of the string "buffer".
            if (lines[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error! Not enogh memory.");
                return 0;
            }
            strcpy(lines[i], buffer);//copies the string "buffer" into "lines[i]".
        }
        printf("Plese enter your comparison string:");
        text = (char*)malloc(80 * sizeof(char) + 1);//allocating temporary memory for the string "text".
        gets(text);//inserting the string "text".
        text = (char*)realloc(text, strlen(text)*sizeof(char)+1);//reallocating the correct memory of "text" according to its exact length and adding an additional memory spot for the chat "\0".
        cmpresult = isEquivalent(lines, length, text);//calling the function
        if (cmpresult == TRUE)//if the function returned TRUE
            printf("The strings are equal.\n\n");
        else printf("The strings are not equal.\n\n");//if the function returned FALSE.
        for ( i = 0; i < length; i++)//free the memory allocated for lines[i].
            free(lines[i]);
        free(lines);//free the memory allocated for the array "lines".
        getchar(option);
    }
```

After debbuging, i found oout that this is the line that crashes my program.

```
for (i=0; i < length; i++)//free the memory allocated for lines[i].
 free(lines[i]);
```

I'm due in a day and I'm desperate! 
Thank you.

Comment: Please format the snippet properly.

Comment: Should you not allocate one byte for the null terminator in your second call to malloc?

Comment: `malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));` --> `malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);`. C strings are 0-terminated. (And simplified because `sizeof(char)` is`1` by definition.)

Comment: You also should not cast the return type of `malloc` in C, this can hide errors if you forget to include its header.

Comment: Look at the three lines starting `text = ...`. First, `text `is not declared. Second, `gets` is deprecated, third, it's useless trying to re-allocate `text` on the basis of what you already entered. The input has already broken the buffer at that point.

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane, that solved it.

Comment: @Shadowwolf i'll take that under consideration,thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane
I don't understand why you didn't _answer_ the question.

Comment: @Motes I didn't know it would completely solve it; I thought I was looking at a "can of worms" because the code posted is incomplete (see my subsequent comment that nobody acknowledged).

Comment: @Shadowwolf Please explain me something, Which kind of compiler this days does compile a program which doesn't have `#include <stdlib>`, when you call `malloc`?

Comment: Trying to compile a program like [This](http://ideone.com/lBeUt1) with a modern compiler like `GCC` you'll get [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/k6WZKJib). Except when you use IDEONE, which should not be used as example

Comment: In C, implicit declarations are allowed. The implicitly declared function will return `int` and take a fixed number of arguments (as provided). You can cast the returned `int` to a pointer type in C. Most compilers will warn you about the implicit declaration though, but this is not required. When you omit the cast, your compiler will have to output a warning since you are then trying to assign an `int` to a pointer without a cast, which is forbidden. Therefor omitting the cast can prevent possible errors in C.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. You don't allocate enough memory for strings. As Weather Vane said, C string are zero-terminated, you need to take account of that '0' and allocate one more byte each time you allocate place for a character string.
2. Don't use `strcpy()` but `strncpy()` instead. This is for security issues. See [Why should you use strncpy instead of strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)
3. For the same reasons, don't use `gets()`
4. `text` is not freed (that's your original problem)

Comment: `strncpy` is worse than `strcpy` imo, because sometimes it produces a non-null-terminated string.  It is correct and less error-prone to allocate the right amount of space and then use `strcpy`

Answer (score 1):

Overflow happens here for each line:

```
gets(buffer);
lines[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
if (lines[i] == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! Not enogh memory.");
    return 0;
}
strcpy(lines[i], buffer); // <----- overflow happens here
```

To fix this change:

```
lines[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
```

to:

```
lines[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

The `realloc()` in the following code does not help with the overflow. By that time overflow has already happened (if it happens).

```
text = (char*)malloc(80 * sizeof(char) + 1);
gets(text); // <----- overflow happens here if string > 80
text = (char*)realloc(text, strlen(text)*sizeof(char)+1);
```