# Segmentation fault with char array member of struct using strcpy()

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, strcpy

I have a `struct TREE` defined this way:

```
typedef struct TREE {
    NODE *head;
} TREE;
```

and a `struct NODE` defined as:

```
typedef struct NODE {
    char boss[30];
    char name[30];
    struct NODE *firstChild;
    struct NODE *secondChild;
    struct NODE *thirdChild;
    struct NODE *fourthChild;
} NODE;
```

In my main, I have:

```
TREE companyStructure;
TREE *treeptr;
treeptr = &companyStructure;
strcpy(treeptr->head->name, "Ben");
```

But this gives me a segmentation fault. Can someone help me explain why this is the case? Is there some memory management that I'm not doing that I need to be doing?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You must not dereference `treeptr->head` before initializing it (`companyStructure.head`).

Comment: Possible (too little possibility to vote for now, I think) duplicate of [c - Why do I get a mysterious crash or "segmentation fault" when I copy/scan data to an uninitialized pointer? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/why-do-i-get-a-mysterious-crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-i-copy-scan-data-to)

Comment: Where do you create the `NODE` structure that  `treeptr->head` points to?  Post that code, too.

Comment: Don't mix `struct <name>` and `typedef` names for the same type! That's just confusing to any reader. And use all-upercase names only for macros and enum-constants.

Comment: It looks to me like the member of treeptr called head has not been initialized. You have to set companyStructure.head to something first.

Comment: Thanks, all. My issue was, as suspected, just that I hadn't initialized companyStructure.head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till,

```
treeptr = &companyStructure;
```

Things look good. But then considering the fact that you have

```
NODE *head;
```

you need to allocate memory for `head`. So most likely you've **missed**

```
treeptr->head = malloc(sizeof *treeptr->head);
```

before doing

```
strcpy(treeptr->head->name, "Ben");
```

---

Also, check [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/1620779) on why should you use `strncat` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I was missing. As a novice with C, I understand how to use pointers but having it nested within the struct was muddying my thinking process. Thanks a lot. I'll check out the link.

Comment: @Nick : You're welcome, I'm sure you'd take no time to master it

Comment: `strncpy` is not a safer version of `strcpy`.  Never use this function, it does not do what you think it does.  It is very error prone.  You can use `strlcpy` for the purpose of truncating the copy to fit in the destination.  `strncpy` does not do that.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy

Comment: @chqrlie : Thankyou for the edit,  appreciated. Agree with what you said, I just had the buffer overflow in mind but the other problems are apparent.