# Stack C++. One element not displayed

Tags: c++, stack

The program reads a text file with the contents

```
A  DPX 

A  QRT
```

Pushes DPX and QRT on stack. But while displaying stack{void show()}, it does not display stack[0]. No idea Why!? It is being pushed onto the stack. element stack[0] diplayed in push() but not in show()

```
const int MAX = 10 ;
struct car
{
        char * lPlate;
        int moves;
};

class garage
{
    private :

        char * stack[MAX] ;
        int top ;

    public :
            garage( )
            {
               top = -1 ;
            }

        void arrive(struct car  c)
         {
            push(c.lPlate);
         }

        void depart(struct car c )
         {

         }

        void push ( char * item ) ;
        char* pop( ) ;
        void show();
} ;

void garage:: push ( char* item )
{
    if ( top == MAX - 1 )
         cout << endl << "Sorry. Parking lot is full" ;
    else
    {
        top++ ;
        strcpy(stack[top] , item) ;
    }
    cout<<"In push: "<<stack[top];
}

char * garage:: pop( )
{
  if ( top == -1 )
    {
        cout << endl << "Parking lot empty is empty" ;
        return NULL ;
    }

    return stack[top--] ;
}

void garage:: show()
{
   cout<<" \nParking Lot Status:\n";
   if( top == -1 )
    {
        cout << endl << "Parking lot is empty" ;
        return ;
    }
    int i=top;
    cout<<"In show "<<stack[0]<<endl;
    while(i>-1)
    {
     cout<<stack[i]<<endl;  i--;
    }
}
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    char *action;
    garage  g;
    ifstream fin("TEST");
    if(!fin){cout<<"Cannot open i/p file \n\n";return 1;}
    char str1[80],str2[40]; int i,j;
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
     fin.getline(str2,MAX);
     struct car c;//create a car obj
     char * pch;
     pch = strtok (str2," ,.-");//split string on getting <space>/<,>/<.>/<->
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
      action=pch;

     pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
     c.lPlate=pch;
     pch=NULL;
     cout<<"\nAction: "<<action<<" lPlate: "<<c.lPlate<<"\n";
      switch(*action)
      {
        case 'A':
            g.arrive(c);
            break;
        case 'D':
            g.depart(c);
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
    }

        fin.close();
        cout<<"\n";
        g.show();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: TL; DR; use a debugger.

Comment: used. everything's working fine. just stack[0] not displayed

Comment: It's too long. Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and pay attention to the last link, [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (Good luck! :-)

Comment: You have an array of pointers. You never initialize the pointers. Then you use the pointers to write where they point. Undefined behavior.

Comment: I see many char pointers there, but no `new` or `malloc`. Are you allocating memory somewhere?

Comment: no. don't work on depart(). just work on arrive() and push() and show().ignore depart() pls

Comment: char pointer is to hold the addr of the string. it works like a char array

Comment: Why didn't you just use `std::string` instead of the `char *` stuff?

Comment: Yes the pointers holds the addresses to where the strings should be. The problem is that you never actually make them *point* anywhere. The pointers will be *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior*. I'm surprised the code doesn't crash actually, as the `strcpy` call will write to seemingly random memory locations.

Comment: everyone pls focus only on push, arrive and show functions

Comment: I am. In the `push` function you use uninitialized pointers. End of story.

Comment: I'm teaching basic c++. no std::string. only array of characters

Comment: Umm `std::string` **is** basic C++.  It has been for the past 18 years.  What you're "teaching" is actually C programming.

Comment: but i am passing c.lPlate to push. its initialised by the passed parameter

Comment: std::string why doesnt it work on turbo C++ v3 then? needs something?

Comment: The problem is the `stack` array. You never initialize it, so its contents is indeterminate. You never make the pointers in `stack` point anywhere. You must allocate memory for them to point to.

Comment: @Coder `turbo C++ v3` -- Why are you using this dinosaur from 20 years ago?  Yes, there is something you need -- an up to date, modern, C++ compiler, something from this generation.

Comment: @Paul : i tried installing visual c++. it says successfully installed. but not found anywhere in the system

Comment: @joachim: if stack array is the problem, how come all except stack[0] displayed?

Comment: [Learn how `strtok` works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok). In your input loop, `c.lPlate=pch;` - that makes your member pointer `lPlace` in your instance `c` point to an address within the buffer `str2`. That buffer will be reused on the next iteration of the loop. loaded with different data and sent through another `strtok` series. Anything that had pointers into that buffer are going to be pointing to what was *last* read. Now think what that means to the rest of your code.

Comment: @Coder *if stack array is the problem...* -- It **is** the problem.  Your code invokes undefined behavior as soon as this line is executed:  `strcpy(stack[top], item);` -- all due to `stack[top]` being uninitialized.  Anything you see happening after that line is pure luck that it is even occurring.

Comment: @Coder turbo c++ development ended in 94 and the brief 2006-2009 revival did not introduce support for much of C++98 never mind C++03, C++11 or C++14. What you are writing is not C++ but C with classes, as evidenced by `struct car c`. Your problem is caused by slogging away at problematic C functionality that C++ has long since addressed. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: From PaulMcKenzie:  "It has been for the past 18 years."  From Coder: "std::string why doesnt it work on turbo C++ v3 then?" Turbo C++ V3 hit the market in 1991. 1991 + 18 = 2009. The current year is 2016. Your compiler is older than standardized C++ (1998). The language has changed  lot in the past 25 years. I won't say it's useless to learn from, but you'll have a hard time finding work in a shop that doesn't use 25 year old technology.

Comment: @Coder its also worth pointing out that a real stack only provides access, addition or removal at the top. What you are implementing is closest to a vector, although a std::map could be a good match for your key (lplate) based lookup.

Comment: Also, can someone suggest a simple C++ compiler. Latest one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array

```
char * stack[MAX] ;
```

is not initialised. It is an array of 10 (MAX) pointers. Each pointer is not initialised.

In the method pop, before copying the item to the stack, initialise the "top" item of the stack

```
top++ ;
int length = strlen(item)+1; //+1 for null terminating character
stack[top] = new char[length]; //allocate memory
strncpy(stack[top] , item, length); //prefer strncpy
```

After reading the file

```
A  DPX 
A  QRT
```

This will result in an array which looks something like this

[image: stack array]

Note

- Gray items remain uninitialised.
- [**Avoid strcpy because it can cause an overflow.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258556/572332) If you must use pointers prefer strncpy.
- Memory allocated to the stack now needs to be correctly **deallocated**, e.g.

  - in the pop method make a copy of the item popped off the stack and delete stack[job] or /and
  - in the deconstructor free the memory that has not been popped.

Change the pop method to something like this

```
int length = strlen(stack[top])+1;
char *returnItem = new char[length];
strncpy(returnItem,stack[top],length);
delete stack[top];
top--;
return returnItem;
```

Who ever calls the pop method needs to deallocate the memory for "returnItem"

In the deconstructor free all memory still held by the stack array, i.e.

```
  ~garage() {
    for (int i=top; i>=0; i--) {
      std::cout << "clean up" << i << std::endl;
      delete stack[i]; 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Uninitializing itself was the problem. Luckily for others except stack[0], it somehow worked. Now, after initializing, its working fine. Whoo!!