# C: Store a list of files in a directory into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, directory

So I want to write a program that goes through a directory and adds file names into an array of strings called "filesList". But the problem is, when it finishes, every element in the array is the name of the last file in the directory. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int n=0, i=0;
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(argv[1]);

//Determine the number of files
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    if ( !strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") )
    {

    } else {
        n++;
    }
}
rewinddir(d);

char *filesList[n];

//Put file names into the array
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    if ( !strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") )
    {}
    else {
        filesList[i]= dir->d_name;
        i++;
    }
}
rewinddir(d);

for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    printf("%s\n", filesList[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whatever solution you use, you'd better hope that nothing adds a file to the directory after you count them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are not allocating memory for your filesList individual elements. You are assisgning it the "dir->d_name" (basically pointing each element of your filesList to a single d_name). You should be doing a malloc for each entry in there.

```
else {
        filesList[i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(dir->d_name)+1);
        strncpy (filesList[i],dir->d_name, strlen(dir->d_name) );
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: You could also just use `strdup()` if available.  [It is standardized by POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you tell me why you used strncpy() instead of strcpy()?

Comment: It's a good practice to always use strncpy instead of strcpy.

read more http://stackoverflow.com/a/1258556/7407065