# C - Too much memory allocated with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I'm working on a project for school, I must create and put binary trees into a dynamic array.
I specify that I'm working on Windows using GCC (GNU compiler).

```
typedef struct s_node * TN;
struct s_node {
    char * chain; //Name of the tree
    int occ; //Number of occurences
    int ht; //Tree's height
};
typedef struct s_binary_tree * TBA;
struct s_binary_tree {
    TN root;
    TBA stl; //Sub Tree Left
    TBA str; //Sub Tree Right
};
```

Firstly I'm allocating memory using malloc() to create an array with x square of binary trees and then I'm allocating the memory for the binary trees.

```
TBA create_Binary_Tree(char * chain, int occ, int number_letters) {
    TBA tree = malloc(sizeof(TBA));
    tree->root = malloc(sizeof(TN));
    tree->root->chain = malloc(sizeof(char) * (number_letters + 1)); //+1 for the '\0'

    *(tree->root->chain) = '\0';
    strcpy(tree->root->chain,chain);
    tree->root->occ = occ;
    tree->root->ht = 1;

    tree->stl = NULL;
    tree->slr = NULL;

    return tree;
}

TBA * create_Array_Binary_Tree(char * fileName) {
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if(!file) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int number_letters;
    fscanf(file,"%d",&number_letters); //number_letters is the number of square that I want to allocate
    TBA * arr = malloc(sizeof(TBA) * number_letters);
    char * letter = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    int occ, i;


    for(i = 0; i < number_letters; i++) { //number_letters = 1 in our example
        fscanf(file,"%s %d",letter,&occ);
        *arr = create_Binary_Tree(letter,occ,number_letters);
    printf("--Adr = %p--\n"arr); //Print the adress
        arr++;
    }
    arr -= i; //Reset the arr pointer

    fclose(file);

    return arr;
}
```

My problem is when I'm calculating the size of the array, the program tells me that the array size x + 38 square.

```
int size_Array_Binary_Tree(TBA * arr) {
    int sz_arr = 0;

    while(*arr != NULL) {
printf("-T = %d\tAdr = %p-\n",sz_arr,arr); //Print the adress
    sz_arr++;
    arr++;
}

return sz_arr;
}
```

Terminal :

```
--Adr = 0000000000951430-- //1 square allocated
-T = 0  Adr = 0000000000951430- //The square allocated
-T = 1  Adr = 0000000000951438- //?
-T = 2  Adr = 0000000000951440- //?
-T = 3  Adr = 0000000000951448- //...
-T = 4  Adr = 0000000000951450-
-T = 5  Adr = 0000000000951458-
-T = 6  Adr = 0000000000951460-
-T = 7  Adr = 0000000000951468-
-T = 8  Adr = 0000000000951470-
-T = 9  Adr = 0000000000951478-
-T = 10 Adr = 0000000000951480-
-T = 11 Adr = 0000000000951488-
-T = 12 Adr = 0000000000951490-
-T = 13 Adr = 0000000000951498-
-T = 14 Adr = 00000000009514A0-
-T = 15 Adr = 00000000009514A8-
-T = 16 Adr = 00000000009514B0-
-T = 17 Adr = 00000000009514B8-
-T = 18 Adr = 00000000009514C0-
-T = 19 Adr = 00000000009514C8-
-T = 20 Adr = 00000000009514D0-
-T = 21 Adr = 00000000009514D8-
-T = 22 Adr = 00000000009514E0-
-T = 23 Adr = 00000000009514E8-
-T = 24 Adr = 00000000009514F0-
-T = 25 Adr = 00000000009514F8-
-T = 26 Adr = 0000000000951500-
-T = 27 Adr = 0000000000951508-
-T = 28 Adr = 0000000000951510-
-T = 29 Adr = 0000000000951518-
-T = 30 Adr = 0000000000951520-
-T = 31 Adr = 0000000000951528-
-T = 32 Adr = 0000000000951530-
-T = 33 Adr = 0000000000951538-
-T = 34 Adr = 0000000000951540-
-T = 35 Adr = 0000000000951548-
-T = 36 Adr = 0000000000951550-
-T = 37 Adr = 0000000000951558-
-T = 38 Adr = 0000000000951560- //?
```

The size returned should be 1, but it returns 39.
Could you please help me?

EDIT : I removed the pointer from types and adapted the rest but the problem still occurs.

```
typedef struct s_node TN;
struct s_node {
    ...
};

typedef struct s_binary_tree TBA;
struct s_binary_tree {
    TN * root;
    TBA * stl;
    TBA * str;
};

TBA * create_Binary_tree(...) {
    TBA * tree = malloc(sizeof(TBA));
    tree->root = malloc(sizeof(TN));
    ...
    return tree;
}

TBA ** create_Array_Binary_Tree(...) {
    ...
    TBA ** arr = malloc(sizeof(TBA *) * number_letters);
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < number_letters; i++) {
        ...
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(TBA));
        arr[i] = create_Binary_Tree(...);
        ...
    }
    ...
    return arr;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `TBA tree = malloc(sizeof(TBA));` is obviously broken. You have the same type on the left (declaring the variable `tree`) and the right side (the argument to `sizeof`). Normally this would look like `T *x = malloc(sizeof (T))` (with a pointer on the left-hand side). Don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in this program:

```
TBA create_Binary_Tree(char * chain, int occ, int number_letters) {
    TBA tree = malloc(sizeof(TBA));
    ...
}
```

`TBA` is a *pointer* to a struct. When you allocate `sizeof(TBA)` you're asking to allocate as much memory as a *pointer* needs, which is just 4 bytes (32 bit) or 8 bytes (64 bit). You want to allocate space for your *struct* instead:

```
TBA tree = malloc(sizeof(struct s_binary_tree));
```

The same problem here:

```
tree->root = malloc(sizeof(TN));
```

should be:

```
tree->root = malloc(sizeof(struct s_node));
```

Only `TBA * arr = malloc(sizeof(TBA) * number_letters);` is actually correct.

[Avoid `strcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy).

Instead of doing messy pointer arithmetics like `arr -= i;`, use a second variable where you store either the original pointer or the one you like to modify.

You are not NULL terminating `arr`. After you allocate it, there may be junk in it. It's best to make sure to fill it with NULLs if you rely on that being a sentinel:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(TBA) * number_letters);
// Or use `calloc`, `bzero`, ...
```

This may be the reason your `size_Array_Binary_Tree` is giving you a strange result.

Comment: Avoiding `strcpy` may be a good idea, but the question you linked to is about `strncpy`, which should never be used (and several answers and comments there agree). `strncpy` is not a safer version of `strcpy`.

Comment: Technically `memset`ting `arr` to all-bits-zero is not required to produce null pointers. C doesn't require null pointers to have a particular representation (and null pointers of different types can have different bits set).

Comment: @melpomene: You're right about `strncpy`, should have picked a better question/answer… can't find one quickly, though. Regarding the null pointers: you're right on that as well but it's irrelevant for a novice programmer as it *is* all zero bits on all machines a typical programmer comes into contact with. Replace it with `for (int i = 0; i < number_letters; ++i) { arr[i] = 0; }` if you want to.

Comment: I change my types, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: @jeanbrick: Did you also initialize the memory of `arr` (using `memset` or the `for` loop I mentioned in my comment to melpomene)?

Comment: @DarkDust: memset is not working, arr[i] = 0 don't work because it's not an int array, I tried calloc but nothing change.