# Isn't strncpy better than strcpy?

Tags: c, strcpy, strncpy

I know there are a lot of answers on the web which say one is better than the other but I have come to this understanding of `strncpy()` is better in terms of preventing unnecessary crashes in the system because of the missing `'\0'`. As many people put it, it is quite defensive.

I have already gone through this link: [Why should you use strncpy instead of strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy)

Let's say:

```
char dest[5];
char src[7] = "Hello";
strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest)-1);
```

With this implementation (the key being `sizeof(dest)-1` which always gives room for the `'\0'` to be appended), even if the destination has a truncated string, isn't it always safer to use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`? In other words, I'm trying to understand when would one want to use `strcpy()` over `strncpy()`?

Comment: When one has complete knowledge of the source and destination, of course. Save oneself a few precious cycles.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `std::string` is better.

Comment: ...but @StoryTeller, since that is impossible as long as the code has not been proven (hence has bugs, ub), defensive programming requires to always use `strncpy`.

Comment: What are you asking that is not already addressed by the answers to the question you linked?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Defensive programming requires `strlcpy`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - What is there to prove when copying c-string literals to buffers of a known size!? :)

Comment: strncpy is better than strcpy but still it's a  debate. I prefers to use strncpy instead of strcpy.

Comment: @StoryTeller, that some increased the string literal that now no longer fits the buffer. (Probably Marketing wanted a nicer message, or so.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - Our complete knowledge has changed, but it's still complete. There's also the matter of the string literal being a poor choice as a user visible label. With i18n to consider, those things shouldn't be hard coded as literals anyway :)

Comment: Your code does, as you say, leave room for the string terminator, but it doesn't put it in, so the resulting string is unterminated. You've just built yourself a trap.

Comment: @PeteBecker [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500151/isnt-strncpy-better-than-strcpy#comment74055761_43500151) is key!  OP was under the false assumption that the code snippet was safe (it formed a string) because `strncpy()` was used and instead it is a problem when code uses `dest` as a string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: To understand when would one use strcpy instead of strncpy.

Comment: If you are fine with writing beyond the end of a buffer, use `strcpy`. If you are more at ease with reading beyond the end of an array, use `strncpy`. If you wish to write well defined code, use `strncpy` and explicitly zero-terminate the destination buffer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: strncpy automatically adds in the null character if sizeof(dest) > sizeof(src). So, dest would then be "Hell".

Comment: @anusha -- RTFM. The effect of `std::strncpy` does not depend on the size of the destination array. It depends on **how many characters you tell it to copy**, and if it hits that limit before seeing a terminator in the source array, the destination **does not get a terminator**. `std::strncpy` is **not** a "safe" replacement for `std::strcpy` under any sensible definition of "safe".

Comment: @PeteBecker: Maybe it's you who should do it. The whole reason why I do sizeof(dest)-1, is just so strncpy appends in the NULL character for that 1 byte that I still have.

Comment: @anusha - PAY ATTENTION: your code **does not terminate the result string**. It tells `strncpy` to copy 4 characters, and since `strncpy` does not hit a terminator in the source string, it **stops** after the fourth character **without** writing a terminator. The result of the copy is something like `"Hell#(ALJLKJ"`, i.e., it has whatever random stuff is in memory starting at `dest[4]`, and any code that uses `dest` is very likely to access memory off the end of the array. That will not end well.

Answer (score 12):

It is not better. Contrary to common belief `strncpy` was not created to replace `strcpy` or to be a safe version of it. It fails to null terminate the string when the source string is larger than the `num` parameter, so you have to do it manually. Like this:

```
strncpy(dst, src, num);
dst[num - 1] = 0;
```

Which requires 2 lines to achieve 1 simple goal and it is easy for developers to forget the second one.

Besides that, it always writes `num` characters (appends `0`'s if necessary) regardless of the sizes of the strings which can be a performance concern when `dst` is small and `num` is large.

Using `strncat` fixes the second problem of writing extra characters but still forces you to write 2 lines:

```
dst[0];
strncat(dst, src, num);
```

The function [`strlcpy`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3) fixes both of these problems but it is not a C standard library function so do not use it.

The right choice is [`snprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) which is guaranteed to null terminate the string and only writes the necessary amount of characters, even if it means truncating the source string.

```
snprintf(dst, size, "%s", src);
```

Comment: Agree `snprintf(dst, size, "%s", src);` is a superior alternative to `strncpy()` for typical use to limit copying.  It does have a weakness in detecting truncated results that is cumbersome.  (too long, encoding error and type change).

Answer (score 4):

In C, `strncpy` has the advantage over `strcpy` that it does not overflow the buffer when the source is larger than the destination.

`strncpy` has the disadvantage that,  when the source is larger than the destination, it *does not* terminate the buffer with a `\0`. So every call of `strncpy` *must* be followed with a statement terminating the buffer, such as

```
strncpy(dst, src, n);
dst[n-1]='\0';
```

User Eugene Sh points out that for defensive programming `strlcpy` must be used: "strlcpy() takes the full size of the destination buffer and
guarantees NUL-termination."

Answer (score 1):

In C++, use `std::string` rather than c-style strings unless performance in a particular area is critical, in which case performance test to see if it is more than a negligible difference. You can use `std::string::reserve` to minimize allocations when you know the size up front.

In my opinion, 85% of bugs are caused by c-style strings. `std::string` is much safer and is less error prone.

In C, you won't have `std::string` available.

If you have to use c-style strings, then I'd prefer `strncpy`, because at least it asks for the size and makes you think about the size, rather than just overflowing.

Comment: Of course, one must also use C strings when one is programming in C, and not C++.

Comment: `My opinion cannot be inaccurate information, it is my opinion.` No, that's not at all true. Saying "In my opinion, *insert random made-up statistics here*" means your opinion is simply **inaccurate**. Regardless of whether it's an opinion or a "fact", it's made-up and it's wrong.

Comment: For your answer to be accurate, you could rephrase that to say something like "In my *experience*, 85% of *bugs*..." or "In my code, 85% of bugs..."

Comment: Sounds like flamewar bait to me. You can feel free to disagree with my opinion in the comments. You don't get to solely decide what is true and what is not, and edit it out in someone else's answer. I prefaced it with "in my opinion", I see no difference between that and "in my experience." It definitely is not "in my code", as I don't use c-style strings if I can help it. I just get to fix other people's bug riddled code for 20 years along the way. Posting a craw of the bug trackers for 7 companies (which I have done) to show 85% of bugs come from c-style strings is not reasonable here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't prevent overflows. It merely exchanges writes past the end with reads past the end. It doesn't zero-terminate the destination for all cases where `strcpy` would have been problematic. You should at least point those dangers out.