# Creating a matrix of strings in C (without malloc and without initializing)

Tags: c, matrix

I want to create a matrix of weekly timetable which must have 8 rows and 5 rows. And each string has 10 chars. It's possible to do that with malloc like that:

```
char ***Schedule = (char ***)malloc(ROW*sizeof(char **));

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
{
    Schedule[i] = (char **)malloc(COL*sizeof(char *));

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        Schedule[i][j] = (char *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
}
```

But I want to not use malloc, because it seems too much lines of code and size of matrix is very little already (8*5*10 = 400 bytes).

```
char Schedule[8][5][10];
```

The above code doesn't work.

```
char *Schedule[8][5];
```

This one works but i don't trust it, because size of strings are uncertain. It may crash.

Comment: 'The above code doesn't work' uh?  Why not?

Comment: post some code that doesn't work using `char Schedule[8][5][10];` ([mcve])

Comment: Note that 10 displayable chars means you need space for 11 bytes.

Comment: writing in strings in `char *Schedule[8][5];` without allocating is just undefined behaviour

Comment: I would have gone with 'Schedule[8][5][128];' anyway, just in case someone wants to schedule some new subject with more chars.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2K6Z4E
doesn't compile. "error: assignment to expression with array type
     Schedule[0][0] = "sdwdwd";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using the `char Schedule[8][5][10]` in wrong way, The correct way would be to do like this (an example)

`scanf("%s",Schedule[i][j]);`

`char *Schedule[8][5]` can be trust if you know that it is basically the 40 `char*` to which you can allocate memory as you want.

For the second case you can allocate in `Schedule[i][j]=malloc(sizeof(char)*n)`

These are the common ways to using char arrays in your code. These are the ways to create a char array and use them. **You wouldn't find other ways to do the same.**

OP asked in comment:

> Scanning the values worked, thanks. But why " Schedule[i][j] = "abc" "
>   doesn't work?

Ans:  You cannot use assignment on an array. Arrays are not assignable in C. Here you can use `strcpy(Schedule[0][0] ,"sdwdwd");` <sup>1</sup>as you know that destination is capable of holding the string lliteral.

<sup>1. Use of strcpy is not advised. Here shown as an example to give user a quick idea. For safer `strcpy` use `strcat` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/3796113)</sup>

Comment: Scanning the values worked, thanks. But why " Schedule[i][j] = "abc" " doesn't work?

Comment: @Atreidex.: You cannot use assignment on an array. Arrays are not assignable in C. Here you can use `strcpy(Schedule[0][0] ,"sdwdwd");` as you know that destination is capable of holding the string lliteral.