# How to assign a string value to two dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

How to assign a string value to two dimensional array in C?

I have a sample code, but its not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char f[20][20];

    f[0]="abc"; //Error Happens Here

    printf("%s",f[0]);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcpy` to copy a string. Try `strcpy(f[0], "abc");`.

Comment: `char b[70]; b="6id4h";`  you cant do this also. char[] cant be l-value.

Comment: First of all, you should use linear arrays.


After that, it's clear how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
f[0]="abc";
```

is wrong as `f[0]` is *char array* and by doing `f[0]="abc";` you are trying to change base address of array `f[0]` which is not possible. you can understand this simply by considering example of one dimensional char array like

```
char arr[10] = "hello";
```

here `arr` means **base address of array** & one can't change that as its **constant pointer**. And now if you do

```
arr = "bye"
```

here you are trying to point `arr` to some other address(`bye` address) rather than earlier base address.

Correct way is

```
strcpy(f[0],"abc");
```

And its better to use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` as pointed by @Eric [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy).

Answer (score 3):

You could try this.

```
void main()
{
    char f[20][20] = {0};
    sprintf(f[0], "abc"); // or strcpy(f[0], "abc"); but I prefer sprintf
    printf("%s",f[0]);
}
```

Actually, any beginner's book in `C` should have told you that arrays (especially strings) are dealt with differently from simple variables such as `int`, `double`, etc...
So.... Happy reading!

Comment: Using sprintf() instead of strcpy() is all well and good until your input string contains a %s (or similar), and then your program crashes.  (Obviously it doesn’t contain one in this case but if the argument was a macro or variable instead of a string literal, that might not be so obvious anymore).  (strncpy() would be even safer)

Comment: `sprintf` is also most likely some ~100 times less efficient than `strcpy`.